# Use of setTimeout - how to pass parameters?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to develop a slideshow with a pause between slides. So I'm trying to use the setTimeout statement as shown below. This is written to swap 2.jpg for 1.jpg with a pause of 10 seconds on clicking the button. But it does now work. Can anyone help me. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var t;
function swap(newImage) {
  var fileName=newImage.toString()+".jpg"
  document.slideshow.src=fileName
  t=setTimeout("swap()",10000)
}
</script>
</head>  
<body> 
  <img name="slideshow" src="1.jpg" width="450" height="335" />
  <br /><br />
  <input type="button" onClick="swap('2')" value="Change image" /> 
  <br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what happens? Show more code. I hope your code doesn't actually look like what you posted here.

Comment: that really doesn't make sense, because the setTimeout action doesn't define an argument, so how could it effectively do anything?

Comment: Answered in better detail at [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of things wrong here. First, its passing code to be eval'ed in the first parameter of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) is not recommended. Better pass a callback instead:

```
 setTimeout(function() { swap(); },10000);
 //Or
 setTimeout(swap,10000); //Passing the actual function as the callback
```

Second, you are calling the swap() method without parameters inside the timeout. It should pass in a new image filename (perhaps by declaring an array of filenames), or check whether the parameter is set or not.

```
function swap(newImage,element) { 
   if(newImage) {
       var fileName = newImage.toString()+".jpg"; 
       element.src = fileName;
   }
   t=setTimeout(this,10000) 
}
```

This function obviously won't do anything after the first run (since no new image filenames are supplied). Using an array you could iterate over several filenames:

```
var images = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg'];
var slideshow = function(element, images, index) {
   if(!index || ( (index + 1) > images.length) ) index = 0;
   element.src = images[index];
   t = setTimeout(function(){
       slideshow(element, images, index + 1);
   },10000) 
};

//Fetch the image element the slideshow is running on
var element = document.slideshow; 
slideshow(element, images);
```

This will continue switching between the images in the array until the timeout is canceled.

Comment: setTimeout can accept a string as the first parameter. that string gets eval()'d so his method would work, if not for forgetting to pass the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Your swap function requires a parameter, so it won't work with setTimeout.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript isn't necessary to do a slideshow.  All you have to do is put each image into a separate page, then add this single line to the top of each page in the <head> section:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=NextPage.html"/>
```

"10" is the number of seconds to wait before going to the next page, and "NextPage.html" is the link to the page containing the next image to display.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I don't see why that's worth a downvote. I try to save those for answers that just plain don't work.