# If element has been 'mouseover'ed for 500ms, run function with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, time

For the sanity of my users, I want a 'mouseover' event to run after the selector has been hovered for half a second rather than as soon as they hover it.

I first tried a setTimeout function but that runs however long the element has been hovered, I didn't think it through too much I guess. I've also spent a day (on and off) searching (and playing Pacman) ti no result, unless I'm searching for the wrong things.

I would like to keep this plugin-less if we can, purely for run speed & maintainability.

```
$("#mySelector").mouseover(function(){
    // Run after 500ms
    $(this).addClass("hasBeen500ms");
});
```

Let's see if we can crack this, I know it will have so many applications!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Prevent from showing up if mouse is already out by the time the delay is expired, plus remove class on mouse out:

```
$("#mySelector").mouseenter(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    el.addClass("hasBeen500ms");
  }, 500);
  el.mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    el.removeClass("hasBeen500ms");
  });
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

`.delay()` wasn't working since `.addClass()` isn't part of the animation queue, so instead I decided to animate something null (decided on `visibility:visible` since you wouldn't be hovering over an invisible element) and then run the add the hover class in the callback function:

```
$('#mySelector').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate({'visibility':'visible'},500,'swing',function(){
        $(this).addClass('hoverIntent');
    })
});

$('#mySelector').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hoverIntent').stop().clearQueue();
});
```

On mouseleave class is removed, and the animation queue is stopped and cleared in case it's prior to 500ms.  You could add the same functionality in the mouseleave if you wanted a delay before unhover.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to cancel the timeout if a person moves the mouse out before the 500 ms has passed:

```
var timer;

$('#mySelector').mouseover(function() {
    timer = setTimeout( function() {$(this).addClass('hasBeen500ms');}, 500);
});

$('#mySelector').mouseout(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.

Comment: That was my first response, then I read that he didn't want to use a plugin.

Comment: @mhr - ah... I obviously skipped over that part. In any case, I still recommend it. It's a known, documented and tested piece of code. It only adds one function to the jQuery object, and it is only 1.2kb minified.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback) about setting a callback to the setTimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to build upon [Web Logic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892187/if-element-has-been-mouseovered-for-500ms-run-function-with-jquery/2892197#2892197)

create a variable to track if mouse is still over said element:

```
var isMouseOver=false;

$("#mySelector").mouseover(function(){
   isMouseOver=true;//set variable to gtrue
   setTimeout(function() {
                 if(isMouseOver){
                      $(this).addClass("hasBeen500ms");
                 }
              }, 500);
});
```

also set `mouseout` callback, so we can track if mouse is still there after 500 ms.

```
$("#mySelector").mouseout(function(){
   isMouseOver=false;//set variable to false
});
```

hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to optimize a bit you can use something like that. This code is adapted for google maps pins but you get the idea

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(){
  this.timeout = setTimeout(markerClick.bind(this, false), 500)
  google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'mouseout', function(){
    if(this.timeout){
      clearTimeout(this.timeout)
      delete this.timeout
    }
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(this, 'mouseout');
  }.bind(this))
}.bind(marker))
```