# How can I access the same variable in recursive call of a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function onload_animate(id_name, img_src1, img_src2, time_ms){
                document.getElementById(id_name).src = img_src1;
                setTimeout("onload_animate(id_name, img_src1, img_src2, time_ms)", time_ms);
                document.getElementById(id_name).src = img_src2;

        }
```

This is my given code. I would like to access the same value of parameters from onload_animate(param1, param2,...) in setTimeout() in each recursive call. How can it be possible??

Comment: You should really try and accept some answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Okay... I got the point of your statement!! I will accept the answer which works!! But, how about if there are more answers that can be accepted Matt?? Thank you at last for your guidance! :)

Comment: Infinite recursion is a great way to cause a stack overflow!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Comment: You should choose the best one. Which was the most helpful, most detailed? Which answer are other people with a similar problem as yours most likely to find helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is considered bad practise to pass `setTimeout` a string. This is similar to using `eval()`, which is evil in JavaScript.

```
function onload_animate(id_name, img_src1, img_src2, time_ms){
    document.getElementById(id_name).src = img_src1;

    setTimeout(function () {
        onload_animate(id_name, img_src1, img_src2, time_ms);
    }, time_ms);

    document.getElementById(id_name).src = img_src2;
};
```

Will capture the variables so they are available within `setTimeout`. Note that this function will currently loop forever; you need some form of exit (usually checking a conditional; e.g. has `time_ms` expired yet?)

Your code should probably look something like this;

```
function onload_animate(id_name, img_src1, img_src2, time_ms) {
    document.getElementById(id_name).src = img_src1;

    setTimeout(function () {
        onload_animate(id_name, img_src2, img_src1, time_ms);
    }, time_ms);
};
```

See this snippet for a working example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/3vKnW/.

JavaScript does not wait for `setTimeout` to complete. It is asynchronous. JavaScript will hit the `setTimeout` line, schedule the function to be ran in `time_ms` time, but will then go back and continue executing where it left off.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to animate a picture continuously. So, I should keep on running this function; right?? But, still it is not working! I have put alert() statement after the last statement of this function, and this alert() statement execute only once.

Comment: That is what I was trying to do!! Thank you Matt! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you put the `settimeout` callback into an anonymous function it should work. That way the parameters stay in scope.

```
function onload_animate(id_name, img_src1, img_src2, time_ms){
                document.getElementById(id_name).src = img_src1;
                setTimeout(
                    function(){
                         onload_animate(id_name, img_src1, img_src2, time_ms);
                    }, time_ms);
                document.getElementById(id_name).src = img_src2;

        }
```

Try reading up about javascript [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), they are very useful.

Comment: Thank you @Laurencek for providing me tutorial about closures!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)?

```
var int=self.setInterval("onload_animate()",time_ms);
```