# javascript function not working after page load

Tags: php, javascript, html, function

why my code is not working? I have called a javascript function after page load PHP script.like below:

```
<script>
setTimeout("fb_login()",100);
</script>
```

`fb_login()` function is on same page

```
function fb_login()
{
alert("ok");
}
```

Tried with  `setTimeout("fb_login",100);` too. but not working.

I have checked console, but it's giving no error.

Comment: Did you try it with exactly `setTimeout("fb_login",100);`, i.e. with the double quotes around `fb_login` OR `setTimeout(fb_login,100);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be you given less time in `setTimeout` but and it's calling your function befor page loaded fully. So Try to increase time.

```
<script>
setTimeout("fb_login()",1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this code:

```
<script>
    setTimeout("fb_login()",100);
</script>
```

to this:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(fb_login,100);
</script>
```

Good explanation from similar post - [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 2):

Just change it to:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(fb_login, 100);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that fb_login is being initialized before calling otherwise it will give error. Either use document.ready or add that function before it is called. Does it give you some error like "fb_login is undefined" ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
   setTimeout(fb_login,100);
};

function fb_login(){
   alert("ok");
}

</script>
```

**EDIT:** first check if the below is working or not, if it does not work then pbm is somewhere else

```
window.onload = function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
     fb_login();
},100);
};
```