# How can I wait In Node.js (JavaScript)? l need to pause for a period of time

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, yield

I'm developing a console script for personal needs. I need to be able to pause for an extended amount of time, but, from my research, Node.js has no way to stop as required. It’s getting hard to read users’ information after a period of time... I’ve seen some code out there, but I believe they have to have other code inside of them for them to work such as:

```js
    setTimeout(function() {
    }, 3000);
```

However, I need everything after this line of code to execute after the period of time.

For example,

```js
    // start of code
    console.log('Welcome to my console,');

    some-wait-code-here-for-ten-seconds...

    console.log('Blah blah blah blah extra-blah');
    // end of code
```

I've also seen things like

```js
    yield sleep(2000);
```

But Node.js doesn't recognize this.

How can I achieve this extended pause?

Comment: @Christopher Allen, Maybe not relevant, but does the job:  
    `require("child_process").execSync('php -r "sleep($argv[1]);" ' + seconds);`

Comment: The [node-sleep](https://github.com/erikdubbelboer/node-sleep) npm module might do the trick (however, I would only use it for debugging)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: Please don't write your own promises! Use `import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises'`.

Answer (score 945, accepted):

**Update Jan 2021**: You can even do it in the Node REPL interactive using `--experimental-repl-await` flag

```
$ node --experimental-repl-await
> const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
> await delay(1000) /// waiting 1 second.
```

A new answer to an old question. Today ( <s>Jan 2017</s> June 2019) it is much easier. You can use the [new `async/await` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).
For example:

```js
async function init() {
  console.log(1);
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log(2);
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

<s>For using `async/await` out of the box without installing and plugins, you have to use node-v7 or node-v8, using the `--harmony` flag.</s>

**Update June 2019:** By using the latest versions of NodeJS you can use it out of the box. No need to provide command line arguments. Even Google Chrome support it today.

**Update May 2020:**
Soon you will be able to use the `await` syntax outside of an async function. In the top level like in this example

```js
await sleep(1000)
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

[The proposal is in stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await).
You can use it today by using webpack 5 (alpha),

Before that becomes available, you can just wrap the script toplevel in a self calling async function:

```
(async function() {
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
console.log(1)
await sleep(1000)
console.log(2)
})()
```

**More info:**

- Harmony Flag in Nodejs: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/
- All NodeJS Version for download: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: I think you forgot the `await` keyword in front of `sleep(1000)`

Comment: This really should be the answer, the sleep node.js package can be troublesome.

Comment: `let sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));` For oneliner freaks like myself :)

Comment: `let sleep = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);` works on Node 7.6+ and improves readability

Comment: This saved my bacon today (specifically the `promisify` recipe @BrianHVB posted).

Comment: This works perfect for me, used it as a RateLimiter for an app

Comment: Note that if you are using this inside a loop, it won't work if you're doing `x.forEach`. You will have to use a modern `for ... of` loop instead, as detailed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: This is a great answer as it sums up the different ways to do it over the years. Please, consider another update at the top using `setTimeout` from `timers/promises`. See the answer from @maxim-orlov which is far below ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71442573/942435))

Comment: If your using Sinon.useFakeTimers in your tests, make sure to not stub setTimeout (which it does by default) or you'll be wondering why this doesn't work like me >_>

Answer (score 755):

The shortest solution without any dependencies:

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
```

Comment: "The height of sophistication is simplicity." -- Clare Booth Luce.
This is by far the best answer, IMO.

Comment: This is obviously much more recent than the other answers, but it's the most elegant as of 2018 that gets the job done in 1 line without any other impacts to the code.

Comment: This is a good one.  You have to be using NodeJS 7.6.0 or above though.  It won't work on older versions.

Comment: `let sleep = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);` is three characters longer but reusable and more readable imo

Comment: To avoid an eslint complaint, call it `resolve` instead of `done`. I.e. `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))`

Comment: shorter version (but less comprehensive): `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000));`

Comment: how would I do this in a non async function?

Comment: Now I don't have to worry about my while loops eating up my CPU resource. Just throw this one liner into the cog and it slows things down and gets the job done.

Comment: I still get this eslint complaint for this solution -
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-promise-executor-return

Comment: Nice job guys upvoting this answer. Next thing is you copy & paste it 50x into your code, what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: This is the best answer imo!

Comment: why can't we convert this return promise to an async/await function?

Answer (score 252):

Best way to do this is to break your code into multiple functions, like this:

```
function function1() {
    // stuff you want to happen right away
    console.log('Welcome to My Console,');
}

function function2() {
    // all the stuff you want to happen after that pause
    console.log('Blah blah blah blah extra-blah');
}

// call the first chunk of code right away
function1();

// call the rest of the code and have it execute after 3 seconds
setTimeout(function2, 3000);
```

It's similar to **JohnnyHK**'s solution, but much neater and easier to extend.

Comment: @LucasSeveryn You're doing something wrong, then. This is a core design pattern.

Comment: And what do you do when the start of the function is not just one function away, but 10 files away from the code that needs to be de-asynchronized ?

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris What?

Comment: use @machineghost's answer for an elegant promise based solution that requires no custom code and supports await/async

Comment: This is async, it means that if function1 terminates before 3 seconds, they start overlapping each other. Then you can't even return and it's almost never utilizable.

The only way I found so far was using `debugger;`

Answer (score 202):

This is a simple blocking technique:

```
var waitTill = new Date(new Date().getTime() + seconds * 1000);
while(waitTill > new Date()){}
```

It's *blocking* insofar as nothing else will happen in your script (like callbacks). But since this is a console script, maybe it is what you need!

Comment: horrible or not, it does a simple `wait`, it blocks and it works for some testing purpose. Exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: perfectly answers the question without 3rd party libs, and is simple. Yet people say "horrible" .... This is great e.g. for simulating heavy CPU load etc. Btw very similar to this https://www.phpied.com/sleep-in-javascript/

Comment: Also this is the required approach if you are trying to simulate something that would slow down the event loop, thus slowing other users/connections as well. Adding delayed callbacks won't impact other users/connections.

Comment: This is a `spin-wait`.

Comment: This is the worst way of sleeping, it blocks the main node thread!

Comment: @Ali that seems to be the goal.

Comment: this is crazy, it blocks everything

Comment: This is a cpu hogger and consumes memory, better reuse the date object instead of creating a new one each time.

Comment: @codebeat It actually doesn't make any difference if you're spin-waiting. That's the spin part!

Comment: This severely impacts the CPU cycle

Comment: This is the only correct answer to the question. The OP asked specifically to call a wait function, return from the function, and continue. (No callbacks, no async anything, no rewriting your whole call stack to handle promises.) The only other solution that does exactly what the OP wanted is to call an external program, for example `SLEEP.EXE` on Windows.

Comment: This burns CPU as fast as V8 allows just to do nothing

Answer (score 165):

Put the code that you want executed after the delay within the `setTimeout` callback:

```
console.log('Welcome to My Console,');
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Blah blah blah blah extra-blah');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: This is terribly messy and generally bad practice, especially if the OP wants the rest of the program to run after that delay. See my answer.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville It's just an example to illustrate the concept.  Obviously you could (should) factor the code into a function call instead instead of using inline code, just like anywhere else.

Comment: @ChristopherKemp: Turns out Node.js has a solution for this called `node-fibers`. [Check it out.](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/)

Comment: This is a great solution, particularly if you don't want to execute any code, you just want to mimic a "sleep" method inside a loop. Nothing wrong with this example.

Comment: this is perfect for delaying on requests coming from client, I used this approach to test my loading spinners on client side

Answer (score 122):

### On Node 7.6.0 or higher

Node supports waiting natively:

```
const sleep = (waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTimeInMs));
```

then if you can use async functions:

```
await sleep(10000); // sleep for 10 seconds
```

or:

```
sleep(10000).then(() => {
  // This will execute 10 seconds from now
});
```

### On older Node versions (original answer)

I wanted an asynchronous sleep that worked in Windows & Linux, without hogging my CPU with a long while loop.  I tried the sleep package but it wouldn't install on my Windows box.  I ended up using:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/system-sleep

To install it, type:

```
npm install system-sleep
```

In your code,

```
var sleep = require('system-sleep');
sleep(10*1000); // sleep for 10 seconds
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: great answer thanks - it made some impossible code possible - this is NOT a spin-wait

Comment: On further research this module relies on deasync which is forked from another deasync github repo. The original repo warns not to use it as it is a hack. It does work but not on all platforms so if you need a cross platform solution avoid this one.

Comment: That's weird.  We use it on both Linux & Windows successfully.  What OS doesn't work?

Comment: looks at the issues on the system-sleep github repo and there's no guarantee this will work in the future - check out the system-sleep code to see what module it uses under the hood then look at the module that was forked from and the warning given

Comment: It looks like its only dependency is here: https://github.com/jakwuh/deasync-promise.  I don't see anything wrong with that project, nor any warnings.  Do I have the wrong project?

Comment: dependency of system-sleep is deasync-promise whose dependency is deasync - and deasync is a fork of https://github.com/vkurchatkin/deasync - you cant sleep the main thread without hacking it in node - which is what deasync does

Comment: yes, i've never experienced probs with it and its great for dev - under the hood I believe it relies on C or C++ which is widely available but I guess on some machines its not and thats when it fails which is why it causes issues - if it fails system sleep falls back to a spin wait which will freeze code execution

Comment: This package doesn't work on Mac OS, and is therefore not cross compatible, and therefore not workable. See https://github.com/jochemstoel/nodejs-system-sleep/issues/4

Comment: @Nuzzolilo That's weird.  We have one developer on Mac OS and he's never mentioned anything wrong.  I suspect it's a specific Mac OS version.  I also updated this answer since sleep is basically built into newer versions of NodeJS.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this solution produces odd results when stdin's raw mode is set to true. My code is hosted here: https://helperbot3.ngrok.io/public/code0.js This is node.js 12.18.2, by the way.

Comment: @user8385393 If you are using node 12.18.2 you should be using the `On Node 7.6.0 or higher` section.

Comment: This should be higher. Brilliant answer

Comment: works like charm. perfect!

Answer (score 70):

## Simple and elegant sleep function using modern Javascript

```
function sleep(millis) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));
}
```

No dependencies, no callback hell; that's it :-)

---

Considering the example given in the question, this is how we would sleep between two console logs:

```
async function main() {
    console.log("Foo");
    await sleep(2000);
    console.log("Bar");
}

main();
```

The "drawback" is that your main function now has to be `async` as well. But, considering you are already writing modern Javascript code, you are probably (or at least should be!) using `async`/`await` all over your code, so this is really not an issue. All modern browsers today [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Browser_compatibility) it.

Giving a little insight into the `sleep` function for those that are not used to `async/await` and fat arrow operators, this is the verbose way of writing it:

```
function sleep(millis) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () { resolve(); }, millis);
    });
}
```

Using the fat arrow operator, though, makes it even smaller (and more elegant).

Comment: You can also write the sleep function without the `async` and leaving everything else the same. It is probably clearer with the `async` though.

Comment: Good catch, @KevinPeña. Matter of fact, I think I prefer it without `async`. Edited my answer with your suggestion. I don't think it makes the code clearer; for that, I'd resort to JSDoc instead.

Comment: I like to have the following one-liner in my scripts: `const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));`

Answer (score 69):

From Node.js 15 and up you can use the [Timers Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers-promises-api). You don't have to promisify `setTimeout` or rely on a 3rd party library anymore.

```js
import { setTimeout } from 'node:timers/promises';

await setTimeout(1000);
```

Comment: This is the correct solution - please don't write your own promises.

Comment: Absolutely the correct solution.

Answer (score 53):

You can use this [www.npmjs.com/package/sleep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep)

```
var sleep = require('sleep');
sleep.sleep(10); // sleep for ten seconds
```

Comment: It works fine on `MacOS`, but it encounter errors on `CentOS` due to [node_gyp errors](https://github.com/erikdubbelboer/node-sleep/issues/23). It seems not portable.

Comment: perhaps problem caused not by OS, but by node build

Comment: This is a newer feature, and so will require a newer version of Node.

Answer (score 44):

If you want to "code golf" you can make a shorter version of some of the other answers here:

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

But really the ideal answer in my opinion is to use Node's `util` library and its `promisify` function, which is designed for exactly this sort of thing (making promise-based versions of previously existing non-promise-based stuff):

```
const util = require('util');
const sleep = util.promisify(setTimeout);
```

In either case you can then pause simply by using `await` to call your `sleep` function:

```
await sleep(1000); // sleep for 1s/1000ms
```

**EDIT:** As noted in the comments, you can even reduce that to one line:

```
const sleep = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);
```

Or, if you don't even want to bother making a `sleep` function:

```
await require('util').promisify(setTimeout)(1000);
```

Comment: Actually, using util.promisify, it is not possible to call sleep without also providing a callback. 

https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args

Comment: You're missing the `await`.  It sort of creates a callback, pauses things, and then restarts the code when that callback returns.  The callback returns with a value, but we don't care about it in this case, so there's nothing to the left of `await`.

Comment: write it in one line to wine the code golf ;) 
const sleep = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);

Comment: @Fabian, and if you need it only once: `await require('util').promisify(setTimeout)(1000);`

Answer (score 35):

This question is quite old, but recently V8 has added Generators which can accomplish what the OP requested.  Generators are generally easiest to use for async interactions with the assistance of a library such as [suspend](https://github.com/jmar777/suspend) or [gen-run](https://github.com/creationix/gen-run).

Here's an example using suspend:

```
suspend(function* () {
    console.log('Welcome to My Console,');
    yield setTimeout(suspend.resume(), 10000); // 10 seconds pass..
    console.log('Blah blah blah blah extra-blah');
})();
```

Related reading (by way of shameless self promotion): [What's the Big Deal with Generators?](http://devsmash.com/blog/whats-the-big-deal-with-generators).

Comment: Good answer - But should read `yield setTimeout(suspend.resume(), 10000);`

Comment: Thanks, @edhubbell. This answer was based on a very old version of suspend, but you're right regarding the latest. I'll update the answer.

Comment: what version of node is this for?

Comment: @danday74 I can't recall exactly when they were un-flagged, but they've been around since v0.12 behind the `--harmony` flag, and according to node.green, they're at least available without any flags since v4.8.4: http://node.green/#ES2015-functions-generators-basic-functionality.

Please note, however, that the newer `async/await` syntax provides a better solution to this now, with no need for extra libraries like `suspend`. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41957152/376789. Async functions are available (without flags) since v7.10.

Comment: This is very complicated [as of 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep/39914235).

Answer (score 30):

Try using promise, it works for me in NodeJS

one liner

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
```

or have it as a function in `NodeJS` to re-use

```
const sleep = async (milliseconds) => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}
```

use the function like

```
await sleep(5000)
```

Answer (score 23):

On Linux/nodejs this works for me:

> const spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync;
>
> var sleep = spawnSync('sleep', [1.5]);

It is blocking, but it is not a busy wait loop.

The time you specify is in seconds but can be a fraction. I don't know if other OS's have a similar command.

Comment: `sleep` is pretty much omnipresent and a utiltiy arround since early UNIX days https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_%28Unix%29. Only "not rare" os it would maybe not exist is windows (however there you could attempt `child_process.spawnSync('timeout', ['/T', '10'])`

Answer (score 19):

**Node 16** has a new way to do it easily

```js
import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises'

console.log('before')
await setTimeout(3000)
console.log('after')
```

Comment: This is literally the same as [Maxim Orlov's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71442573/1762224) answer.

Answer (score 14):

I've recently created simpler abstraction called **wait.for** to call async functions in sync mode (based on node-fibers). There is also a version based on upcoming ES6 Generators.

https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

Using **wait.for**, you can call any standard nodejs async function, as if it were a sync function, without blocking node's event loop.

You can code sequentially when you need it, which is, (I'm guessing) perfect to simplify your scripts for personal use.

using **wait.for** your code will be:

```
require('waitfor')

..in a fiber..
//start-of-code
console.log('Welcome to My Console,');
wait.miliseconds(10*1000); //defined in waitfor/paralell-tests.js - DOES NOT BLOCK
console.log('Blah blah blah blah extra-blah');
//endcode.
```

Also any async function can be called in *Sync* mode.
Check the examples.

Comment: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'miliseconds'`

Comment: the comment says: "//defined in waitfor/paralell-tests.js" grab it from that file.

Comment: after I got it from `wait.for/paralell-tests.js` I encountered a another errors related to undefined properties etc. So I needed to copy them too. Why don't you organize the code in a way that this will not be required?

Comment: Wait.for and other fiber solutions have opened up a whole new world to me! I'd up vote this a million times if I could. Although most of the nodejs community oppose fibers, I think they're a fantastic addition and definitely have their place when it comes to callback hell.

Answer (score 10):

Since, javascript engine (v8) runs code based on sequence of events in event-queue, There is no strict that javascript exactly trigger the execution at after specified time. That is, when you set some seconds to execute the code later, triggering code is purely base on sequence in event queue. So triggering execution of code may take more than specified time.

So Node.js follows,

```
process.nextTick()
```

to run the code later instead setTimeout(). For example,

```
process.nextTick(function(){
    console.log("This will be printed later");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With ES6 supporting `Promise`s, we can use them without any third-party aid.

```
const sleep = (seconds) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, (seconds * 1000));
    });
};

// We are not using `reject` anywhere, but it is good to
// stick to standard signature.
```

Then use it like this:

```
const waitThenDo(howLong, doWhat) => {
    return sleep(howLong).then(doWhat);
};
```

Note that the `doWhat` function becomes the `resolve` callback within the `new Promise(...)`.

Also note that this is ASYNCHRONOUS sleep. It does not block the event loop. If you need blocking sleep, use this library which realizes blocking sleep with the help of C++ bindings. (Although the need for a blocking sleep in Node like async environments is rare.)

https://github.com/erikdubbelboer/node-sleep

Answer (score 1):

In order to "wait" in javascript using promises are the way to go as the top answers show.

So how can it be used?

Here's a simple example of a 5-second sub-process queuing up parameters for a 4-second main process in a non-blocking manner.

```
const wait = (seconds) => 
    new Promise(resolve => 
        setTimeout(() => 
            resolve(true), seconds * 1000))

const process = async (items, prepTask, mainTask) => {
    const queue = [];
    let done = false;

    items.forEach((item, i) => {
        prepTask(item).then(() => {
            queue.push(item);
            if (i == items.length -1) {
                done = true;
            }
        })
    })

    while (!done || queue.length) {
        if (queue.length) {
            const workload = queue.shift();
            await mainTask(workload)
        } else {
            console.log('waiting for subtask to queue')
            await wait(1);
        }
    }
}

// Usage Example

const ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

const prepTask = async (id) => {
    await wait(id * 5)
    return id * 5;
}

const mainTask = async (workload) => {
    console.log('excuting workload: ', workload);
    const result = await wait(4);
    return { workload, result }
}

process(ids, prepTask, mainTask)
    .then(() => console.log('done'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let co = require('co');
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

co(function*() {
    console.log('Welcome to My Console,');
    yield sleep(3000);
    console.log('Blah blah blah blah extra-blah');
});
```

This code above is the side effect of the solving Javascript's asynchronous callback hell problem. This is also the reason I think that makes Javascript a useful language in the backend. Actually this is the most exciting improvement introduced to modern Javascript in my opinion. To fully understand how it works, how generator works needs to be fully understood. The `function` keyword followed by a `*` is called a generator function in modern Javascript. The npm package `co` provided a runner function to run a generator.

Essentially generator function provided a way to pause the execution of a function with `yield` keyword, at the same time, `yield` in a generator function made it possible to exchange information between inside the generator and the caller. This provided a mechanism for the caller to extract data from a `promise` from an asynchronous call and to pass the resolved data back to the generator. Effectively, it makes an asynchronous call synchronous.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks @DonaldDuck. The code in my answer is probably the most exciting part of improvement in Javascript. I'm so amazed that some super smart people think about this way to solve the callback hell problem.

Answer (score 0):

simple we are going to wait for 5 seconds for some event to happen (that would be indicated by done variable set to true somewhere else in the code) or when timeout expires that we will check every 100ms

```
    var timeout=5000; //will wait for 5 seconds or untildone
    var scope = this; //bind this to scope variable
    (function() {
        if (timeout<=0 || scope.done) //timeout expired or done
        {
            scope.callback();//some function to call after we are done
        }
        else
        {
            setTimeout(arguments.callee,100) //call itself again until done
            timeout -= 100;
        }
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

For some people, the accepted answer is not working, I found this other answer and it is working for me: [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

```
var hello = "Hello World";
setTimeout(alert, 1000, hello);
```

'hello' is the parameter being passed, you can pass all the parameters after the timeout time. Thanks to @Fabio Phms for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a moment.js flavored module based on the [dirty blocking approach suggested by @atlex2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37575602/1889273). *Use this only for testing*.

```
const moment = require('moment');

let sleep = (secondsToSleep = 1) => {
    let sleepUntill = moment().add(secondsToSleep, 'seconds');
    while(moment().isBefore(sleepUntill)) { /* block the process */ }
}

module.exports = sleep;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doThen(conditional,then,timer) {
    var timer = timer || 1;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(conditional()) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            then();
        }
    }, timer);
}
```

Example usage:

```
var counter = 1;
doThen(
    function() {
        counter++;
        return counter == 1000;
    },
    function() {
        console.log("Counter hit 1000"); // 1000 repeats later
    }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to suspend for testing purpose you current thread execution try this:

```
function longExecFunc(callback, count) {

    for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        for (var i = 1; i < (1 << 30); i++) {
            var q = Math.sqrt(1 << 30);
        }
    }
    callback();
}
longExecFunc(() => { console.log('done!')}, 5); //5, 6 ... whatever. Higher -- longer
```

Answer (score -2):

The other answers are great but I thought I'd take a different tact.

If all you are really looking for is to slow down a specific file in linux:

```
 rm slowfile; mkfifo slowfile; perl -e 'select STDOUT; $| = 1; while(<>) {print $_; sleep(1) if (($ii++ % 5) == 0); }' myfile > slowfile  &
```

node myprog slowfile

This will sleep 1 sec every five lines. The node program will go as slow as the writer.  If it is doing other things they will continue at normal speed.

The mkfifo creates a first-in-first-out pipe.  It's what makes this work.
The perl line will write as fast as you want.  The $|=1 says don't buffer the output.

Answer (score -3):

I put together, after having read the answers in this question, a simple function which can also do a callback, if you need that:

```
function waitFor(ms, cb) {
  var waitTill = new Date(new Date().getTime() + ms);
  while(waitTill > new Date()){};
  if (cb) {
    cb()
  } else {
   return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

For more info on

```
yield sleep(2000);
```

you should check [Redux-Saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga). But it is specific to your choice of Redux as your model framework (although strictly not necessary).