# Alternative ways of calling javascript code sequentially with delays in between

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, timedelay

I have this code originally in python.

```
SendSerialPortCommand("XXX")
time.delay(0.5)
SendSerialPortCommand("YYY")
```

I converted this code to node.js but the code looks much uglier.

```
SendSerialPortCommand("XXX");

setTimeout(function () {
    SendSerialPortCommand("YYY");
}, 500);
```

Imagine if my python code looks like this.

```
SendSerialPortCommand("XXX")
time.delay(0.5)
SendSerialPortCommand("YYY")
time.delay(0.5)
SendSerialPortCommand("AAA")
time.delay(0.5)
SendSerialPortCommand("BBB")
```

The node.js code will look really ugly with `setTimeout()` inside `setTimeout()`.

How can the node.js code be improved in terms of readability? I don't care about violating asynchronous nature of javascript for this question. Important thing is readability.

Comment: The nested timeouts is a variation of the asynchronous ['pyramid of doom'](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/03/14/nodejs-and-asynchronous-programming-with-promises/). One alternative approach is to use some form of streams: this includes promises.

Answer (score 5):

#### 1. One-liner solution:

[Previously accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242606/4354249)  just complicates the things, and not brings any readability or improvement. Do it like this then, just **one-liners**:

```
setTimeout(function(){ SendSerialPortCommand("XXX"); }, 500);
setTimeout(function(){ SendSerialPortCommand("YYY"); }, 1500);
setTimeout(function(){ SendSerialPortCommand("ZZZ"); }, 2000);
```

#### 2. Simple configurable solution:

If you want to **make it configurable**, move options to the config above, and **call in the loop**, alike:

```
var schedulerData = [
   {delay: 500,  params: "XXX"},
   {delay: 1500, params: "YYY"},
   {delay: 2000, params: "ZZZ"}
];

for (var i in schedulerData) {
    var doTimeout = function(param, delay) {
        setTimeout(function(){ SendSerialPortCommand(param); }, delay );
    };
    doTimeout(schedulerData[i].params, schedulerData[i].delay);
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06zf893b/), to play with.

#### 3. Using node module `node-fibers`

If you want advanced solution through node.js to "show off", you may go **[`node-fibers`](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers)** way, and to create **sleep** function, alike in their manual.

```
var Fiber = require('fibers');

function sleep(ms) {
    var fiber = Fiber.current;
    setTimeout(function() {
        fiber.run();
    }, ms);
    Fiber.yield();
}

Fiber(function() {
    SendSerialPortCommand("XXX");
    sleep(1000);
    SendSerialPortCommand("YYY");
}).run();
console.log('still executing the main thread');
```

`node-fibers` implemenation is being used in tons of other smaller libraries, alike [WaitFor](https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor). More information could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14249506/4354249).

#### 4. Using `Promise` & `Deferred` Objects

You can create a **Promise** based timeout function. [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36315321/4354249) described one of possible implementations. But I will provide small code snippet, for easier understanding on how it actually works, using `Defferred` from jQuery:

```
function wait(ms) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(deferred.resolve, ms);
    // We just need to return the promise not the whole deferred.
    return deferred.promise();
}

// Use it
wait(500).then(function () {
    SendSerialPortCommand("XXX");
}).wait(500).then(function () {
    SendSerialPortCommand("YYY");
});
```

If promises are not supported, you will need to get *polyfills* for *ECMAScript*, for example [Promises from **`core-js`** package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js#ecmascript-6-promise) or any other standalone component of *Promises/A+ implementation*.

*Deffered*, might be gotten as separate [**`Deffered`** package for NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deferred) as well, the [concept is nicely described here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deferred#deferredpromise-concept).

Answer (score 2):

You could use promises:

```
function Delay(duration) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), duration);
  });
}

function SendSerialPortCommand(command) {
  // Code that actually sends the command goes here...
  console.log(command);
  return Promise.resolve();
}


Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => SendSerialPortCommand("XXX"))
  .then(() => Delay(500))
  .then(() => SendSerialPortCommand("YYY"))
  .then(() => Delay(500))
  .then(() => SendSerialPortCommand("AAA"))
  .then(() => Delay(500))
  .then(() => SendSerialPortCommand("BBB"));
```

Or, including the delay into the SendSerialPortCommand:

```
function SendSerialPortCommand(command, duration) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Code that actually sends the command goes here...
      resolve();
    }, duration);
  });
}

Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => SendSerialPortCommand("XXX", 500))
  .then(() => SendSerialPortCommand("YYY", 500))
  .then(() => SendSerialPortCommand("AAA", 500))
  .then(() => SendSerialPortCommand("BBB", 500));
```

Node 4+ is required for using arrow functions, but this can be done without them easily, if needed.

Comment: one might need to make it work on old versions of NodeJS: then one would need to get *polyfills* for *ECMAScript*, for example [Promises from **core-js** package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js#ecmascript-6-promise) or as standalone component implementation, e.g. [Promises/A+ implementation](https://github.com/kevincennis/promise)

Answer (score 0):

Take note of the timings in running the functions later.

```
var scheduler = (function(){
    var timer;
    function exec(call, delay){
        //clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(call, delay);
    };
    return exec;
})()

SendSerialPortCommand("XXX");
scheduler(function(){SendSerialPortCommand("YYY")}, 500);
scheduler(function(){SendSerialPortCommand("AAA")}, 1000);
scheduler(function(){SendSerialPortCommand("BBB")}, 1500);
```

Comment: Since all the timers are started at once this will 'drift' compared to the original, especially if the called function takes relevant time.

Comment: what if one of the functions being executed takes longer than the delay diff you specified? I guess mixing this with promises would be the right thing to do

Comment: strange solution, why it's less uglier, than one-liners?! Not getting this. Make [them configurable, or do one-liners with Timers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36309007/4354249), without over-complication.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for alternative ways I'll write one as well.

```
var commandIterator = 0;
var portCommands = [
   'YYY',
   'AAA'
];
SendSerialPortCommand(portCommands[commandIterator++])

var yourInterval = setInterval(function(){
   SendSerialPortCommand(portCommands[commandIterator++])
}, 500);
```

At any point you need to stop the execution of those commands you just call 
`clearInterval(yourInterval)`

If you're still concerned with readability you could enclose the iterator inside the setInterval and wrap contents in a nice clean function. Good luck!