# Can't access Mongo from Node container running in Istio

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes, istio

I'm trying to run a stateful Mongo inside Kubernetes and it works with these configurations outside of Istio.

```
  mongodb: {
    uri: "mongodb://mongo-0.mongo,mongo-1.mongo,mongo-2.mongo",
    dbName: "app"
  }
```

But when I run the node application inside Istio, it loses the ability to connect to the mongo. Is there something I'm missing or is it so that I can't use stateful-sets with Istio yet?

---

stateful mongo config below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    service: mongo
  name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    service: mongo
    role: mongo
***********
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
        service: mongo
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo:3.4.6
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "10m"
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--replSet"
            - rs0
            - "--smallfiles"
            - "--noprealloc"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
        - name: mongo-sidecar
          image: cvallance/mongo-k8s-sidecar
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "10m"
          env:
            - name: MONGO_SIDECAR_POD_LABELS
              value: "role=mongo,environment=test"
```

Error that I'm receiving is

```
[2017-07-25 12:01:11] ERROR Mongoose MonboDB connection error: {
  "message": "write EPIPE",
  "name": "MongoError",
  "stack": "Error: write EPIPE\n    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)\n    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:851:14)"
}
[2017-07-25 12:01:11] ERROR ... retrying createConnection in 5 seconds... 
[2017-07-25 12:01:16] ERROR Mongoose MonboDB connection error: {
  "message": "read ECONNRESET",
  "name": "MongoError",
  "stack": "Error: read ECONNRESET\n    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)\n    at TCP.onread (net.js:610:25)"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StatefulSet support has been recently added, but it's not in a release yet.

https://github.com/istio/pilot/pull/896

Comment: Thaks! Didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 0):

For ones who are receiving such error in istio with manual injection:

When you are injecting proxy to your deployment, **network is dropped while istio-proxy is configured**:

```
kubectl apply -f kubernetes-configs/
istioctl kube-inject -f kubernetes-configs/deployment.yml | kubectl -n foo apply -f -
```

In that time, you will receive:

```
Error: write EPIPE
```

I solved problem by adding pause before initialization like in this question: [How Can I Wait In Node.js (Javascript), l need to pause for a period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249506/how-can-i-wait-in-node-js-javascript-l-need-to-pause-for-a-period-of-time)

---

**UPDATE**

Here is the another way. Just let nodejs app restart. By invoking `process.exit(137)` in any place where connection is not successful, **Docker container will be killed and restarted**. In that time, istio-proxy will finish network configuration and your app will successfully connect to DB.