# How to sleep in Node.js v9+ with ES6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, wait, sleep

It's year 2018 and modem node is of version 9 or 10, i.e., the ***accepted*** answer from [How Can I Wait In Node.js in year 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249506/) is no good any more. Hence I'm asking it again, as per [the guidance of meta here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258363/old-question-new-technology-new-answer).

The criteria for the answer now is to use existing ES6 and Node.js v9+ features without any extra packages.

I found the answer from @treecoder at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44036791/2125837
particular interesting, but I just can't make it work for my case:

```
$ node
> const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

> const waitThenDo = async (howLong, doWhat) => await sleep(howLong*1000).then(doWhat)

> waitThenDo(1, console.log(2))
2
Promise {
  <pending>,
 ...
```

I.e., the `waitThenDo` does the printing right away, without any delay.

What I've done wrong, and/or, what the best latest technology to wait/sleep?

Comment: Just FYI: The @ notation to ping someone only works if they have written an answer or comment to this specific question. You can't just reach out and touch someone at random here; this isn't a chatroom or social networking site. It's also inappropriate to address your question to a single person. If you want to personalize your questions, hire a contractor that you can correspond with directly.

Comment: ok. thanks for the kind explanation.

Comment: `doWhat` needs to be a callback *function*.

Comment: Try `async function waitAndLog() { await sleep(1000); console.log(2); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **then** method of a promise expects a function:

```
waitThenDo(1, () => console.log(2))
```

You could also do this:

```
const waitThenDo = async (howLong, doWhat) => {
  await sleep(howLong*1000)
  doWhat()
}

waitThenDo(1, () => console.log(2))
```