# Async in for loop, Nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, asynchronous, request, async-await

I am wanting the for loop to run sequentially, finishing one loop completely before moving to the next. The loop is putting a JSON message into another JSON message then sending it to a function that begins posting to an api. I need that function to complete before moving on to the next item in the JSON. p is the item name that is being used to post back whether it was successfully posted to the db via the api service.

Here is the bit of code simplified for this question.

```
let processJson = function(items) {
    for (const p in items) {
        let newObj = {
            "key1": items[p].key1,
            "key2": items[p].key2,
            "keySpecial": items[p].key3 + items[p].key4
        };
        await validateJson(p, newObj);
    }
};
```

I need the validateJson to finish its chain of asynchronous work before moving on to the next p in the loop.

How can I do this?

Here is the validateJson function as requested.

```
const validateJson = function (id, jsonObj) {
    const processItemSchema = {
        "properties": {
            "key1": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "key2": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 3,
                "maxLength": 3
            },
            "keySpecial": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 4,
                "maxLength": 4
            }
        }
    };
    const ajv = new Ajv();
    let validate = ajv.compile(processItemSchema);
    let valid = validate(jsonObj);
    if (!valid){
        resCallback(id + ": invalid JSON");
    }
    else{
        // Generate Special Flag(s) value, Comma Separated Value
        let specialFlag = "";
        specialFlag += specialCheck1(jsonObj.keySpecial);
        if(specialFlag.length > 0) {
            let temp = specialCheck2(jsonObj.keySpecial);
            if (temp.length > 0) {
                specialCheck += "," + temp;
                maintenanceCall(id, jsonObj, specialFlag);
            }
            else {
                mainenanceCall(id, jsonObj, specialFlag);
            }
        }
        else {
            specialFlag += specialCheck1(jsonObj.keySpecial);
            maintenanceCall(id, jsonObj, specialFlag);
        }
    }
};
```

More Code as requested

```
const maintenanceCall= function (id, jsonObj, specialFlag) {
        request.post({
            url: 'https://url.poster/something',
            auth: {
                'user': 'user',
                'pass': 'pass',
                'sendImmediately': true
            },
            json: true,
            body: {
                "Input": {
                    "InputParameters": {
                        "KEY": jsonObj.key1,
                        "Hole": jsonObj.Key2,
                        "SomeWhere": jsonObj.keySpecial
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        , function (error, response, body) {
            if (body.OutputParameters.X_MSG_DATA !== null) {
                resCallback(id + , Message: "
                    + body.OutputParameters.DATA);
            }
            else {
                const sampCheck = function(smsFlag){
                    if(flag=== "Y")
                        return ".X";
                    else if(flag=== "N")
                        return "";
                    else
                        resCallback(id + ": this item can not be processed");
                    processItem(id, jsonObj, stats);
                }
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `validateJson`? It needs to be changed.

Comment: Please post the actual code so that a solution can be determined.

Comment: I don't see any asynchronous operations there, they must be in `resCallback` or in `maintenanceCall`?

Comment: What does `resCallback()` do?  Is it synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: Also, what does `processItem()` do and is it sychronous or asynchronous?

Comment: If it's a different rest API, then it's ASYNCHRONOUS and it needs to return a promise too.  I've shown you how to promisify things in my answer and how to return promises to work with `await`.  It's up to YOU to fix the rest of your code to work similarly.  We don't write all your code for you here.  We teach you how to write code so you can make the rest of your code work properly.  Please attempt to take what I've taught you in my answer below and apply it to the rest of your code.  If you get stuck on that, then post a new question that shows your current code is and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

To "pause" your `for` loop using `await`, you have to be awaiting a promise.  So you have to make `validateJson()` return a promise that resolves when any asynchronous operations inside that function are done.  That's how `async/await` works in Javascript.

It is not clear exactly what is or isn't asynchronous in `validateJson()`.  If nothing is asynchronous, then it's just serial execution and you don't need `await` or promises at all.  Javascript is single threaded so it will just run `validateJson()` until it's done and the `for` loop will be blocked until `validateJson()` returns.

If `validateJson()` does have some asynchronous operations in it, then you have to make sure that `validateJson()` returns a promise that resolves only when all those asynchronous operations are done.  Then, and only then, can you use `await` to "pause" your `for` loop while your asynchronous operations run.  To help you fix `validateJson()`, we would have to understand more about what is and isn't asynchronous and what interface the asynchronous operations have for knowing when they are done.  Then, we could help you make `validateJson()` return a promise that resolves at the right time to make your `await` work properly.

Also, you can only use `await` inside a function that is declared `async` so you would also have to add that to the `processJson()` definition.

```
let processJson = async function(items) {
```

---

To illustrate the concept, here's a simple example that you can run right here in the snippet to see how it pauses the `for` loop:

```js
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

async function run() {
    console.log("starting...");
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        await delay(1000);
        console.log("Timer " + i + " fired");
    }
    console.log("done");
}

run();
```

---

Now that you've added more code, we can talk about your real code (though it is still unclear what `resCallback()` or `processItem()` do so this may not yet be the end of changes.

First change `maintenanceCall()` to return a promise which I will do mostly by switching to the request-promise module and returning that promise:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const maintenanceCall= function (id, jsonObj, specialFlag) {
        return rp.post({
            url: 'https://url.poster/something',
            auth: {
                'user': 'user',
                'pass': 'pass',
                'sendImmediately': true
            },
            json: true,
            body: {
                "Input": {
                    "InputParameters": {
                        "KEY": jsonObj.key1,
                        "Hole": jsonObj.Key2,
                        "SomeWhere": jsonObj.keySpecial
                    }
                }
            }
        }).then(function(body) {
            if (body.OutputParameters.X_MSG_DATA !== null) {
                resCallback(id + , Message: "
                    + body.OutputParameters.DATA);
            }
            else {
                // FIX THIS: You define this function here, but never use it, that's odd
                const sampCheck = function(smsFlag){
                    if(flag=== "Y")
                        return ".X";
                    else if(flag=== "N")
                        return "";
                    else
                        resCallback(id + ": this item can not be processed");
                    processItem(id, jsonObj, stats);
                }
            }
        });
};
```

Now that `maintenanceCall()` returns a promise, you can use that in `validateJson()` like this so it always returns a promise:

```
const validateJson = function (id, jsonObj) {
    const processItemSchema = {
        "properties": {
            "key1": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "key2": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 3,
                "maxLength": 3
            },
            "keySpecial": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 4,
                "maxLength": 4
            }
        }
    };
    const ajv = new Ajv();
    let validate = ajv.compile(processItemSchema);
    let valid = validate(jsonObj);
    if (!valid) {
        resCallback(id + ": invalid JSON");
        return Promise.reject(new Error(id + ": invalid JSON"));
    } else {
        // Generate Special Flag(s) value, Comma Separated Value
        let specialFlag = "";
        specialFlag += specialCheck1(jsonObj.keySpecial);
        if(specialFlag.length > 0) {
            let temp = specialCheck2(jsonObj.keySpecial);
            if (temp.length > 0) {
                specialCheck += "," + temp;
            }
        } else {
            specialFlag += specialCheck1(jsonObj.keySpecial);
        }
        return maintenanceCall(id, jsonObj, specialFlag);
    }
};
```

And, then you can go back to your `processJson()` function and make your `for` loop run serially like this:

```
let processJson = async function(items) {
    for (const p in items) {
        let newObj = {
            "key1": items[p].key1,
            "key2": items[p].key2,
            "keySpecial": items[p].key3 + items[p].key4
        };
        await validateJson(p, newObj);
    }
};
```

And, the caller can use `processJson()`like this:

```
processJson(someItems).then(() => {
   console.log("all done here");
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: @gray - Since you added more code, I added more to my solution.

Comment: @gray - I have no idea what "no longer captures input" means?  You haven't included all your code so I've shown appropriate modifications to the code you've shown.  You could be getting an error.  Are you logging all errors and use `.catch()` where you call  `processJson()`?  But frankly, I have no idea what that comment means so I can't do anything with that.  I've put a lot of energy into trying to help you, but you are making it very difficult by not clearly describing problems and by not including ALL relevant code.

Comment: @gray -  Well, there's no `console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode)` anywhere in the code I suggested because there's no `response` variable in the code I suggested (I'm using the request-promise library which does not use that parameter and it checks the status code for you automatically and turns non-200 responses into rejected promises) so I have no idea what code you're trying to run.  I'm going to sleep now.  Good luck.

Comment: @gray - Yeah, that's the way it's designed here.  Errors stop the flow.  That can easily be changed with an appropriate `.catch()` handler.  Not sure what your requirement is or what you want it to do when there are errors or what errors are OK to proceed on and which ones not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node-async-loop
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-async-loop

```js
var asyncLoop = require('node-async-loop');
 
var array = ['item0', 'item1', 'item2'];
asyncLoop(array, function (item, next)
{
    do.some.action(item, function (err)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
 
        next();
    });
}, function (err)
{
    if (err)
    {
        console.error('Error: ' + err.message);
        return;
    }
 
    console.log('Finished!');
});
```

Comment: JSON data's can be any type, if your JSON data is array then it would be work, just try

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want to rewrite and restructure all of their code. For those who don't want unnecessary complexity. For those who want an item in their for loop to finish posting before the next item is looped through. For those who like to keep it simple. For these.. Here it is.

```
/**
 * Clever way to do asynchronous sleep. 
 * Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46720712/778272
 *
 * @param {Number} millis - how long to sleep in milliseconds
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function sleep(millis) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));
}

async function run() {
    const urls = await fetchUrls(INITIAL_URL);
    for (const url of urls) {
        await sleep(10000);
        const $ = await fetchPage(url);
        // do stuff with cheerio-processed page
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want your code-block to run sync, use this JavaScript function:

```
// Your loop..
{
  (function (p) 
  {
      // Your code...
  })(p);
}
```