# Making the bot stop sending messages if a user hasn't sent a message within x minutes

Tags: discord.js

I have a !trivia command which has 4 functions and inside the functions I have a `.then()` function and `.setTimeout()`. The problem is that once someone triggers the command, it will only stop once someone say '!stop'. How can I make it so it stops if no one typed in that channel within 5 minutes?

Comment: A quick google will pull up this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249506/how-can-i-wait-in-node-js-javascript-l-need-to-pause-for-a-period-of-time    I would suggest using an asynchronous function or your bot will stop, but it should otherwise be the same. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)

```js
let userUsingTheCommand = "<USER_ID>";
let filter = msg => msg.author.id = userUsingTheCommand;
// Errors: ['time'] treats ending because of the time limit as an error
function wait() {
  channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
      max: 1,
      time: 60000 * 5,
      errors: ['time']
    })
    .then(wait)
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("Time to stop!");
    });
}
```

Comment: And if i don't want someone else to use that command while a trivia is going on, can i do the same?

Comment: Thats what `filter` does. It checks if `msg.author.id` equals to `userUsingTheCommand`. When the user starts the trivia, save their ID to `userUsingTheCommand`

Comment: I added your code in a totally new file just to check it out.it didn't really print someone in the console. Did i do something wrong?