# Check messages in each 10 min intervals kafka - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Consumer should check messages at each 10 min intervals this time response message should contains from uncommitted offset,
Currently messages getting once producer send message

Answer (score -1):

That's not really how a Kafka Consumer works. Usually, you have an infinite loop and just take whatever messages are given to you. Unless you're changing the group.id and not committing offsets between requests, you'll always get the next batch of messages.

If you want to add some max consumption limit, followed by a 10 minutes to sleep a thread within that loop, then that's an implementation detail of your application, but not specific to Kafka

Comment: Can you give an example for this

Comment: An example of an infinite loop in Node? Or sleeping a thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249506/how-can-i-wait-in-node-js-javascript-l-need-to-pause-for-a-period-of-time