# How to install an upload/app into Device farm remote session

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-device-farm

I am facing issue in **devicefarm.installToRemoteAccessSession**.

I am successfully able to create a remote session using **aws-sdk** from lambda function. Next, i tried to install an already existing upload into the created remote session.

```
code

 let remoteSession = await devicefarm.createRemoteAccessSession(params).promise()
.then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      let installParm = {
        appArn: uploadArn,
        remoteAccessSessionArn: res.remoteAccessSession.arn
      };
      devicefarm.installToRemoteAccessSession(installParm).promise()
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
      return res;
    })
    .catch(err => err);
```

I am getting the below error. [i replaced the id's with *]

```
message: 'Invalid parameters RemoteAccessSession or Upload with identifiers: arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:*:session:**/**/00000 or arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:*:upload:***/**.',
code: 'ArgumentException',
```

Whether I can give **upload ARN** for **appArn**. what is the difference between these two? If appARN or different where can i get?

Comment: I'm still testing this but I think the code will just need to wait for the upload to be processed. So if the upload doesn't have the status of SUCCEEDED then the install command would fail.

Comment: So the parameters you gave are valid. That error I believe appears when the session is not in a running state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason in my case after I reproduced this was because the remote access session had not started yet. I had requested one, but the Device Farm service didn't acquire a device at the same time which is expected.

After I waited for the session to begin by watching the web console the upload was successful. So the code would need to have some check there to see the status of the remote access session using the [get-remote-access call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DeviceFarm.html#getRemoteAccessSession-property) and the status attribute returned.

**Update**

I wrote this javascript code to wait for the remote session to go to a status of `RUNNING`.

```
// assume we already executed `npm install aws-sdk`
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// assumes `npm install https`
const request = require("request");
// assumes `npm install fs`
const fs = require('fs');
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/41641607/8016330
const sleep = (waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTimeInMs));
// Device Farm is only available in the us-west-2 region
var devicefarm = new AWS.DeviceFarm({ region: 'us-west-2' });

let params = {
    name: "test of remote access"
};
devicefarm.createProject(params).promise().then(
    function (data) {
        /* process the data */
        console.log("created project", "Result: ", data.project.arn);
        let project = data.project;
        let params = {
            name: "app-debug.apk",
            type: "ANDROID_APP",
            projectArn: project.arn
        };
        devicefarm.createUpload(params).promise().then(
            function (data) {
                console.log("Created upload object successfully", "upload arn: ", data.upload.arn);
                console.log("uploading file...");

                var options = {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    url: data.upload.url,
                    headers: {},
                    body: fs.readFileSync("./aws-device-farm-sample-app-for-android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk")
                };

                new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                        if (error) {
                            reject(error);
                        }
                        resolve(data);
                    });
                }).then(function (data) {
                    console.log("successfully uploaded file");
                    console.log("waiting for the sdk to finish processing");

                    getUploadStatusAndCreateRemoteSession(data.upload.arn,project).then(function (status) {
                        if (status == "SUCCEEDED") {

                        }

                    });
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.error("Error uploading file", "Error: ", err);
                });
            },
            function (error) {
                console.error("Error creating upload object", "Error: ", error);
            }
        );
    },
    function (error) {
        console.error("Error creating project", "Error: ", error);
    }
)

async function getUploadStatusAndCreateRemoteSession(uploadarn,project) {
    await devicefarm.getUpload({ arn: uploadarn }).promise().then(
        function (data) {
            console.log("getting upload status is successful", "Status: ", data.upload.status);
            if (data.upload.status != "SUCCEEDED") {
                sleep(5000).then(() => {
                    getUploadStatusAndCreateRemoteSession(data.upload.arn,project);
                });
            } else {
                // return data.upload.status;
                devicefarm.createRemoteAccessSession({
                    projectArn: project.arn,
                    deviceArn: 'arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2::device:CF6DC11E4C99430BA9A1BABAE5B45364'
                }).promise().then(
                    function (session) {
                        //get session status
                        getSessionStatus(session.remoteAccessSession.arn,uploadarn);
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        console.error("Error creating remote access sesssion", "Error", error);
                    }
                );
            }
        },
        function (error) {
            console.error("Failure getting upload", "Error: ", error);
            return error;
        }
    );
}

async function getSessionStatus(sessionArn,upload) {
    await devicefarm.getRemoteAccessSession({ arn: sessionArn }).promise().then(
        function (data) {
            console.log("getting session status is successful", "Status: ", data.remoteAccessSession.status);
            if (data.remoteAccessSession.status != "RUNNING") {
                sleep(5000).then(() => {
                    getSessionStatus(sessionArn,upload);
                });
            } else {

                console.log("Remote access session started!", "Installing app...");
                let installParm = {
                    appArn: upload,
                    remoteAccessSessionArn: sessionArn
                };
                devicefarm.installToRemoteAccessSession(installParm, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) console.error(err);
                    else console.log(data);
                });

            }
        },
        function (error) {
            console.error("Failure getting session", "Error: ", error);
            return error;
        }
    );
}
```

**Output**:

```
created project Result:  arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:111122223333:project:42ca0449-2714-4dd8-848f-ae9ef6655efb
Created upload object successfully upload arn:  arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:111122223333:upload:42ca0449-2714-4dd8-848f-ae9ef6655efb/cd200f8e-e7f7-4d18-a4ee-32ad959a0786
uploading file...
successfully uploaded file
waiting for the sdk to finish processing
getting upload status is successful Status:  PROCESSING
getting upload status is successful Status:  SUCCEEDED
getting session status is successful Status:  PENDING
getting session status is successful Status:  PENDING
getting session status is successful Status:  PREPARING
getting session status is successful Status:  PREPARING
getting session status is successful Status:  PREPARING
getting session status is successful Status:  PREPARING
getting session status is successful Status:  PREPARING
getting session status is successful Status:  PREPARING
getting session status is successful Status:  PREPARING
getting session status is successful Status:  PREPARING
getting session status is successful Status:  PREPARING
getting session status is successful Status:  PREPARING
getting session status is successful Status:  PREPARING
getting session status is successful Status:  PREPARING
getting session status is successful Status:  RUNNING
Remote access session started! Installing app...
{ appUpload:
   { arn: 'arn:aws:aatp:us-west-2:111122223333:upload:42ca0449-2714-4dd8-848f-ae9ef6655efb/cd200f8e-e7f7-4d18-a4ee-32ad959a0786',
     name: 'app-debug.apk',
     created: 2019-05-04T00:24:32.871Z,
     type: 'ANDROID_APP',
     status: 'SUCCEEDED',
     url: 'https://prod-us-west-2-uploads.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Adevicefarm%3Aus-west-2%3A111122223333%3Aproject%3A42ca0449-2714-4dd8-848f-ae9ef6655efb/uploads/arn%3Aaws%3Adevicefarm%3Aus-west-2%3A111122223333%3Aupload%3A42ca0449-2714-4dd8-848f-ae9ef6655efb/cd200f8e-e7f7-4d18-a4ee-32ad959a0786/app-debug.apk?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20190504T002655Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJSORV74ENYFBITRQ%2F20190504%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=4630cef6030405b6997281c2477722d3da24eb04ed6aab8e91735d936e532807',
     metadata: '{"device_admin":false,"activity_name":"com.amazonaws.devicefarm.android.referenceapp.Activities.MainActivity","version_name":"1.0","screens":["small","normal","large","xlarge"],"error_type":null,"sdk_version":"10","package_name":"com.amazonaws.devicefarm.android.referenceapp","version_code":"1","native_code":[],"target_sdk_version":"22"}',
     category: 'PRIVATE' } }
```

HTH

James

Comment: It worked as expected. But the **createRemoteAccessSession** doesn't return me _endpoint_ of the remote session. So using that, i can directly access the session. And once again, Thanks for your effort.

Comment: You're welcome, it may be the case that the createRemoteAccessSession doesn't return the endpoint because the device is not acquired yet. I'll test it and let you know

Comment: I just print the result of the getRemoteAccessSession api call in my code I ran locally and the endpoint attribute is there after the session has a state of **RUNNING**. I think this is expected too since the web socket can't exist before the device has been acquired.

Comment: I just tried, when the status is **RUNNING** i am getting the endpoint. ` "endpoint": "wss://devicefarm-interactive.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?X-Amz-Date=*&X-Amz-Credential=*" `. I was expecting a http URL, can we use the above URL format to open the remote session on browser?

Comment: Probably not, but you could crew that URL easily by using the session Arn.

Comment: exactly i was doing that. What could be the use of endpoint URL then, any idea?

Comment: It's the web socket URL. So if you wanted to create your own web console you could create a web socket connection and send the device commands from the users mouse.