# To many requests exception when testing nodejs api

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm testing a nodejs api, but it allows 5 requests per second.

When testing this rate is quick exceeded, has anyone an idea on how tot tackle it?

I'm testing with mocha and chai-js (chaiHttp)

Comment: You can wait 1 second every 5 request. Maybe this awnser helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/14249587/10781258

Comment: limiter https://www.npmjs.com/package/limiter was made for problems like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that is was due to a throttle on the server, had to set a variable in test env to fix it