# How to force the nodejs app to stop from the scheduler?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to force my cron task to stop and actually want the whole nodeapp to stop after 5 executions, but nothing happens, the message "time to quit" keeps appearing in log every minute.

What is the best way to stop the cron job and the quit the whole docker?

```
const crone = require('node-cron');
let mucount = 0;
export const update = crone.schedule('1 * * * * *', () => {
    
    if (mucount < 5) {
        new UpdateController();
        mucount++;
    } else
        
        {log.info("time to quit")
            update.cancel();
            update.stop();
             server.close();
             process.kill(process.pid);
             process.exit(1);
             throw new Error('Please exit');
            
        }
},{ scheduled: false });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `node-cron` is spawning child processes, and trying to kill those child processes is not exiting the parent process, which makes sense for most use cases. You can try defining a kill method outside the cron function and then invoking it inside the cron function, though generally the whole reason you would use a scheduled cron function like this is to run something on a schedule *without* exiting after a few occurrences.

My advice would be to use a different method of running `new UpdateController()` five times, with a minute in between, which automatically exits after it finishes. Depending on your requirements this might be achieved using some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249506/how-can-i-wait-in-node-js-javascript-l-need-to-pause-for-a-period-of-time) on waiting in NodeJS for a fixed amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try calling update.stop() from outside the execution block?

Not familiar with this api.

Comment: Can you make a code example?

Comment: Just add it to the last line of your file..