# How do I call a function (wait a few seconds) and then call another?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a program where I basically have this button that I made in CSS, and I want him to (when clicked) flash a color, and then 200ms later, return the color to normal, and for some reason I can't get it to work right

```js
function highlight_button(button_id){
    button_id.style.backgroundColor="yellow"
    sleep(200)
    button_id.style.backgroundColor="red"
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
        currentDate = Date.now();
        } 
    while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

 highlight_button(myButton);
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Press</button>
```

what I thought would happen was the following:
-the button would appear yellow immediately
-the program would wait 0.2 seconds
-the button would appear red

however...
the following happens:
-the program would wait 0.2 seconds
-the button would appear red

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` to execute code 200ms later.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a `sleep()` function.

Comment: the reason I had a sleep function was because setTimeout() didn't let me give arguments in the functions.
p.s. I had forgotten to show the sleep function and I have already edited it

Comment: You don't need any arguments. `setTimeout(() => button.style.backgroundColor="red", 200)`

Comment: Your code doesn't work because the DOM changes aren't rendered until JavaScript returns to the main event loop.

Comment: thanks man, it works, I'm quite new to the syntax of javascript (since I used python for so god damn long) thanks

Comment: `new to the syntax of javascript (`,  it's not really the syntax here, but the way JS runs an event loop.  Basically all JS work inside a browsers main thread should never block for long periods of time.   The good news, modern JS has `async / await`, and working to these restrictions isn't as hard as it used to be.. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I wait In Node.js (JavaScript)? l need to pause for a period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249506/how-can-i-wait-in-node-js-javascript-l-need-to-pause-for-a-period-of-time)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  // Code to run later goes here.
  console.log('Timeout completed!');
}, 2000); // Time till execution, in milliseconds.
```

The callback will be called after the specified delay.

Answer (score 0):

use setTimeout(). your code just hangs the browser. or better use CSS transition or animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
function highlight_button(button_id) {
  button_id.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

highlight_button(id);
setTimeout(() => {
  button_id.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let button_id = document.querySelector("#myButton");

async function highlight_button(button_id){
    button_id.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
   //waits promise to be all settled
   await sleep(500)
    button_id.style.backgroundColor="red"
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
     setTimeout(() =>{
    //some task can be done
    
    //promise will be in pending until it gets resolved/rejected
    resolve(true);
   }, milliseconds)
  })
}

 highlight_button(myButton);
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Press</button>
```