# Prevent Playwright test from timing out after 30 seconds

Tags: playwright

Is there a way to force Playwright to wait for a specific amount of time, say 15 minutes?  I have tried using `page.waitForTimeout(900000);`, but this throws an error: "Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded". Sometimes, there is no message, just a fail status at the `page.waitForTimeout(900000);` statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249506/how-can-i-wait-in-node-js-javascript-l-need-to-pause-for-a-period-of-time

Comment: @ggorlen OP didnt mention Jest..

Comment: This is a *bad practice* to put hardcode wait for so long during tests. It simply means , there is something needs to be fixed in your app immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails because default Playwright timeout is 30 sec. You can change it in the config file or directly in the test. See docs - https://playwright.dev/docs/test-timeouts#test-timeout

```js
test("Example", async ({ page }) => {
  test.setTimeout(150_000);

  await page.waitForTimeout(120_000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Avoid Hard Waits

> Hard waits only do one thing: they just wait for the fixed
> amount of time. There is nothing more to them. This makes them
> dangerous: they are intuitive enough to be favoured by beginners and
> inflexbile enough to create serious issues.

#### This is a *bad practice* for various reasons, please don't do this:

- If an event is taking so long in normal app processing , most likely it's performance level application bug.
- It waits for long time in a static way means regardless of actual application state which either reached to expected or unexpected state long before or after this hard wait. Basically it does not control anything.
- it increases the overall execution time significantly
- if it's running sequentially atleast for the test cases in the same file , they are unnecessary blocked.

> The biggest issue I have observed in automation code reviews, once
> a team start using hardcoded waits , it *becomes a norm rather than
> exception* and grows all over the code base.

Reference: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/3765
https://www.checklyhq.com/learn/headless/avoiding-hard-waits/