# Nodejs: How to pause or sleep script execution inside a for loop

Tags: node.js

How do i pause execution of a nodejs script in a for loop.

code

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const word_lst = fs.readFileSync("wordlist.txt", "utf-8").split("\n");

var i = 0;

word_lst.forEach(async function(word){
  i += 1;
  if (i % 10 == 0) {
    console.log('Sleeping..');
    // do something here
  }

  console.log(`${i}. ${word}`)
  });
```

I tried using `setTimeout` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41957152)  but unfortunately it doesn't work when it's in loop

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const word_lst = fs.readFileSync("wordlist.txt", "utf-8").split("\n");

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
var i = 0;

word_lst.forEach(async function(word){
  i += 1;
  if (i % 10 == 0) {
    console.log('Sleeping..');
    await sleep(1000)
  }

  console.log(`${i}. ${word}`)
  });
```

output: `sleep` is not being executed and no errors are displayed either.

Comment: Use an actual loop, not the `forEach` method

Comment: @Bergi sorry but Can you please share code cause i still can't figure it out

Comment: Have you seen [the linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)? Please [edit] your question to add your attempt