# Javascript Function Encapsulation

Tags: javascript

i am getting `undefined undefined` when i defined and call the `setTimeout` function as follow:

```
var person = {
    first: 'joe',
    last: 'doe',
    getName: function(){
        console.log(this.first + ' ' + this.last);
    }
}

setTimeout(person.getName(), 2000);
```

unless if i wrap the `person.getName()` in a function as follow:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    person.getName()
}, 2000);
```

Now i am getting a right output. Why it's so?

Comment: Did you call the settimout function before you initialize person

Comment: Actually your first example works and puts `joe doe`, but doesn't wait for the timeout…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you meant:

```
var person = {
    first: 'joe',
    last: 'doe',
    getName: function(){
        console.log(this.first + ' ' + this.last);
    }
}

setTimeout(person.getName, 2000);
```

The reason you get undefined is that what you are effectively doing is :

```
var somefunc = person.getName; 
setTimeout(somefunc, 2000);
```

So somefunc gets called in the context of window. i.e. window.somefunc()

However when you do

```
setTimeout(function(){
    person.getName()
}, 2000);
```

The context of getName is preserved as you are Calling (not passing around) person.getName

Comment: What he's effectively doing is `var somefunc = person.getName();`, which sets `somefunc()` to whatever `person.getName()` returns. Context is not the problem, the issue is calling versus referring.

Answer (score 1):

I have just answerd for something similar here :

[How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback/16801862#16801862)

The setTimeout function fix the context to the window, so it's not possible to do what you want !

To do it i have wrapped the setTimeout function in another one which can set the context :

```
myNass_setTimeOut = function (fn , _time , params , ctxt ){
return setTimeout((function(_deepFunction ,_deepData, _deepCtxt){
            var _deepResultFunction = function _deepResultFunction(){
                //_deepFunction(_deepData);
                _deepFunction.apply(  _deepCtxt , _deepData);
            };
        return _deepResultFunction;
    })(fn , params , ctxt)
, _time) 
};

// lets try this functions :
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   setTimeout(function(){console.log(i)} ,1000 ); // stock setTiemout in closure
}

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   setTimeout( console.log(i) ,1000 ); // stock setTiemout direct call 
}

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   setTimeout(console.log ,1000 , i); // stock setTiemout not compatible IE
}

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   myNass_setTimeOut(console.log ,1000 , [i] , console); // wrapped setTimeout
}
```

So to answer your question :

```
var person = {
    first: 'joe',
    last: 'doe',
    getName: function(){
        console.log(this.first + ' ' + this.last);
    }
}

setTimeout(person.getName(), 2000);
```

When you launch : `setTimeout(person.getName(), 2000);` setTimeout will execute in the future 2s (2000ms) the 1st argument !

But what is the value of your 1st argument ? : the result of your function person.getName`( )`,
so it's equivalent of :

```
var _arg1 = person.getName();
setTimeout(_arg1 , 2000);
```

which is very different of :

```
var _arg1 = person.getName;
setTimeout(_arg1 , 2000);
```

The first case you pass the result of a function to setTimeout which wait a reference to a function.
In the second case you pass a reference to a function (good it's what expected), but not in the good context !

So, now you have to fix the context :
whith the core javascript function :[apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fapply)

Now try this :

```
var _arg1 = function(){ person.getName.apply(person) };
setTimeout(_arg1 , 2000);
myNass_setTimeOut(person.getName , 2000 , null , person);
```

So you have two choice :

- Fixing the context for every argument you pass to setTimeout.
- Use a function which do it for you

the myNass_setTimeOut function will make the trick !

Now, let see something a little bit more deeper :

```
var person = {
        first: 'joe',
        last: 'doe',
        getName: function(){
            console.log(this.first + ' ' + this.last);
        } ,
        say : function(sentence){
             console.log(this.first + ' ' + this.last + ' say : ' + sentence)
        }
    }
```

How could pass argument sentence to a setTimeout ?

```
var heSay = "hello !"; setTimeout(person.say(heSay) , 1000 ); heSay = "goodBye !";
// not good : execute immediatly

var heSay = "hello !";setTimeout(function(){person.say(heSay)} , 1000 ); heSay = "goodBye !";
// not good : hesay googbye

var heSay = "hello !"; setTimeout(person.say , 1000 , heSay); heSay = "goodBye !";
// not good bad context

var heSay = "hello !"; setTimeout(function(whatHeSay){person.say(whatHeSay)} , 1000 , heSay);heSay = "goodBye !";
// GOOD ! ok but not compatible with IE

var heSay = "hello !"; myNass_setTimeOut(person.say , 1000 , [heSay] , person ); heSay = "goodBye !";
// just good !
```

hope this help you !

**edit :**

for modern browser suporting bind don't take care about that do what say 
[here @dandavis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16826369/2037556)

Answer (score 0):

1. you call it too early.
2. the this gets broken when you save a function ref without the object it's attached to.

solution?

use bind and don't call it early:

```
var person = {
    first: 'joe',
    last: 'doe',
    getName: function(){
        console.log(this.first + ' ' + this.last);
    }
}

setTimeout(person.getName.bind(person), 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first function works fine for me (tested in Chrome):

http://jsfiddle.net/fzrxK/1/

```
var person = {
    first: 'joe',
    last: 'doe',
    getName: function(){
        alert(this.first + ' ' + this.last);
    }
}

setTimeout(person.getName(), 2000);
```

Perhaps there's another issue elsewhere?

Comment: I updated the code for an 'alert' instead of console.log - still seems to work fine for me both ways...

Comment: Ahh - I understand you now.  Seems there was more than one error in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `person.getName()` executes the function and returns `undefined` (as nothing was declared to return in that function).

What you wanted was:

```
setTimeout(person.getName, 2000);
```

Calling `setTimeout(person.getName(), 2000);` sets a timeout to execute the results returned by `person.getName()` which is `undefined` rather than a function.

Calling `setTimeout(person.getName, 2000);` sets a timeout to execute the function `person.getName`.

With parenthesis executes the function. Without parenthesis passes the variable (which happens to be defined as a function).

**Edit:** As @Isaac points out, passing the function `person.getName` in also changes the behavior of `this` so that is likely not what you wanted either.

Comment: `setTimeout(person.getName, 2000)` is what he actually did, otherwise he wouldn't have got the `undefined undefined` output in console…

Answer (score 0):

```
var person = {
    first: 'joe',
    last: 'doe',
    getName: function(){
        console.log(this);
    }
}
person.getName()
setTimeout(person.getName, 2000);
```

Outputs:

```
Object {first: "joe", last: "doe", getName: function}
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
```

My guess is, JavaScript pulls the `getName` function out of the scope of `person`

Comment: You are right: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/

Comment: Also, note that `setTimeout(person.getName, 2000);` is different to `setTimeout(person.getName(), 2000);`

Comment: `person` is not a scope. It's the context of the call `person.getName()`, and also that function never was "in" there to be "pulled out"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science) Well actually, `scope == context`, so I'd still be correct