# Javascript pass variable through recursive function

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create a recursive function in Javascript. But in order to loop my XML file properly I am trying to pass the right value taken from the XML `length` and pass it to the `setTimeout` function.
The problem is that the `setTimeout` ( `setTimeout('cvdXmlBubbleStart(nextIndex)', 3000);` 
)function does not get the value of `nextIndex` and thinks it is `undefined`. I am sure I am doing something wrong.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
cvdXmlBubbleStart('0');
});

function cvdXmlBubbleStart(nextIndex) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "cross_video_day/xml/broadcasted.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        success: function(d) {
            broadcastedXML = d;
            cvdBubbleXmlProcess(nextIndex);
        }
    });
}

function cvdBubbleXmlProcess(nextIndex) {
    var d = broadcastedXML;
//console.log(nextIndex);
    var length = $(d).find('tweet').length;
    if((nextIndex + 1) < length) {


    nextIndex = length - 1;


    $(d).find('tweet').eq(nextIndex).each(function(idx) {
        var cvdIndexId = $(this).find("index");
        var cvdTweetAuthor = $(this).find("author").text();
        var cvdTweetDescription = $(this).find("description").text();
        if (cvdTweetAuthor === "Animator") {
            $('#cvd_bubble_left').html('');
            obj = $('#cvd_bubble_left').append(makeCvdBubbleAnimator(cvdIndexId, cvdTweetAuthor, cvdTweetDescription));
            obj.fitText(7.4);
            $('#cvd_bubble_right').html('');
            setTimeout('$(\'#cvd_bubble_left\').html(\'\')', 3000);
        } else {
            $('#cvd_bubble_right').html('');
            obj = $('#cvd_bubble_right').append(makeCvdBubble(cvdIndexId, cvdTweetAuthor, cvdTweetDescription));
            obj.fitText(7.4);
            $('#cvd_bubble_left').html('');
            setTimeout('$(\'#cvd_bubble_right\').html(\'\')', 3000);
        }

    });

         }else{
         $('#cvd_bubble_left').html('');
            $('#cvd_bubble_right').html('');
         }    
        //broadcastedXMLIndex++;
        setTimeout('cvdXmlBubbleStart(nextIndex)', 3000); 
}
```

Comment: Try to pass a function to `setTimeout` instead of a string: `setTimeout(function(){cvdXmlBubbleStart(nextIndex);}, 3000)`

Comment: Has string support been removed? Not saying it's a good idea, but [last time I checked it still worked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

Comment: OP: You should use the function as shown in streetlogics' answer. As written you'd need to *construct* the string, e.g., `"cvdXmlbubbleStart('" + nextIndex "')"`. Although it baffles me why you'd use a string if it's an index.

Comment: @DaveNewton no, string support is there but it depends on where the string is evaluated. The string doesn't remember its closure.

Comment: @basilikum The string doesn't need to--the string just needs to be appropriately built using the value of nextIndex. Still broken in terms of what should be done, but should work.

Comment: @DaveNewton - That would work as well.

Comment: @DaveNewton sure, that's a possible solution. But passing the name of the variable in the string as OP did it doesn't work because the string is not evaluated where it was created.

Comment: @basilikum Which is why I showed how to make it work--*I* know why it didn't work, but I wanted the OP to understand that it *could* work, and that it shouldn't be done like that--but that it's doable.

Comment: @DaveNewton Well your question just sounded like you were wondering why the string version didn't work and why people suggest passing a function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an anonymous function will work because it shares the same scope as `nextIndex`.

```
setTimeout(function(){cvdXmlBubbleStart(nextIndex);}, 3000);
```

The reason that your current code does not work for you is because when you use a string inside of the `setTimeout` function it uses the `Function` constructor to create a `function` based on the string passed (which is similar to using `eval` and is not best practice). What is worse here is that the function created with `Function` will not share the same scope as where it was created and thus not have access to `nextIndex`.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback) - basically you need to pass an anonymous function to the set timeout call

```
setTimeout(function(){
    cvdXmlBubbleStart(nextIndex)
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Are strings no longer supported? [It's still shown as doable on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

Comment: @DaveNewton - strings are supported, they go into the `Function` constructor