# Can you pass arguments to a function called from EventListener?

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling

I'm replacing inline event handling with EventListners in the JS file. I'm stuck on one of the form

```
onclick="funcMain(func1(document.getElementById('foo')), func2(document.getElementById('bar'))"
```

since I can't do

```
document.getElementById('offendingInlineElement').addEventListener.('onclick', funcMain('document.getElementById('foo')), func2(document.getElementById('bar'), false)
```

How can I pass  arguments to the function `funcMain`?

Out of curiousity when a function is past like this is it known as a function pointer or is this something else?

Comment: why don't you just create a function that calls document.getElementById('foo') inside of it? Why do you need to pass this as an argument?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an anonymous function:

```
var inlineElement = document.getElementById('offendingInlineElement');

inlineElement.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //write any piece of code you desire here
    funcMain(document.getElementById('foo'));
}, false);
```

Comment: I don't think this can be write because there's no mention of `bar` or `func1` or `func2`. Did you mean `function(){
    funcMain(func1(document.getElementById('foo')), func2(document.getElementById('bar'))`

Comment: @Celeritas it was just an example. You call any function with any parameters you want inside of the anonymous function.