# How do I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?

Tags: javascript, parameters, settimeout

What is the difference between this:

```
function blankWord(){
    console.log('blank!');
    setTimeout(blankWord, 5000);
}
blankWord();
```

Which calls the function every 5 seconds as it should, and this:

```
function blankWord(t){
    console.log('blank!');
    setTimeout(blankWord, t);
}
blankWord(5000);
```

Which calls the function repeatedly insanely fast?

Comment: `setTimeout(blankWord, 5000, 'word')`?

Comment: Answered extensively at [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are missing the parameter in the second form you pass `undefined` from the second call on, which will essentially result in a timeout of 4ms ([which is the browser minimum](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers)).

Use a function wrapper, to safely pass the parameters you need:

```
function blankWord(t){
    console.log('blank!');
    setTimeout(function(){blankWord(t)},t);
}
blankWord(5000);
```

Passing the parameters as third parameters knocks out older IEs, that's why you should not use this until IE8 is dead.

Answer (score 6):

The first script calls setTimeout with a second argument of `5000` every time.

The second script calls it with `t`. The first time that is `5000` (from `blankWord(5000);`). Each subsequent time it is `undefined` (from `setTimeout(blankWord`).

If you want to pass arguments, do so by passing them in an array as the third argument of `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(blankWord, t, [t])
```

See [mdn for a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) to support older browsers that don't recognise the three argument form of the function.

Comment: using the third parameter is a bad idea, because it's not supported by all browers, use a function wrapper instead.

Comment: Why not? Not supported on all browsers? (< IE9 )

Comment: @putvande Sure. IE8 is (sadly) still in use.

Comment: @Christoph — Or use the polyfill which I referenced in the answer.

Comment: @Igal — It no longer gets security updates. Some people still insist on using it.

Comment: Was it ever an array you needed to pass to `setTimeout` as the third parameter instead of individual arguments, i.e. `setTimeout(blankWord, t, t, ...etc);`? The [polyfill at that time](//web.archive.org/web/20140721080333/https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Callback_arguments) did expect `setTimeout(func, delay, arg1, arg2)` syntax.