# use ajax request json output in settimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a var in jquery after a request like

```
         type: 'POST',
     data: data,
     cache: false,
     success: function (data) {
         var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

I'm trying to use timeout to fire the function below after five seconds.

```
        $("#a" + json.id).fadeOut(300);
```

At the moment I'm doing

```
          setTimeout('$("#a" + json.id).fadeOut(300)', 500);
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: When you pass a `String` to `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`, it'll be `eval`uated in the global scope, where `json` isn't available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` takes a function and a number as a parameter, try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#a" + json.id).fadeOut(300);
}, 500);
```

Comment: Firebug says typeError: ("#a" + json.id).fadeOut is not a function

Comment: See my edit, I forgot to put a `$` in front of `("#a" + json.id).fadeOut(300)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the value of json.id changes by the time the timeout callback is called.

Consider the following example:

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
  setTimeout(function(){console.log(i)},500);
}
```

The callback function sees i=10 because that's the value of i by the time the function is invoked. You can do a pre-binding by using closure:

```
var f=function(id){
  setTimeout(function(){console.log(id);},500);
}

for (var i=0;i<10;i++) f(i);
```

Now that you see how closure and pre-binding work, here's a more robust solution to your question:

```
var f=function(id){
  setTimeout(function(){$('#a'+id).fadeOut(300);},500);
}

f(json.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because the String is eval'ed in global context. So for it to work you can make json global (remove the var).

Also, while I am not sure where you are calling the `setTimeout` from, but assuming it is inside the callback, you can alternatively make the id a part of the string :

```
setTimeout('$("#a'+json.id+'").fadeOut(300)', 500);
```

But certainly a better option is to avoid eval and globals at all costs (checkout [Eval is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx) and [Why global state is the devil](http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it) for an elaborate explaination) and pass in a closure :

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#a" + json.id).fadeOut(300); }, 500);
```