# Function not called asynchronously if I pass in an argument

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, settimeout

I am trying to play around with callback functions. I wanted to make my callback async and from what I understand, one of the ways is to call the `setTimeout` function to make my synchronous function, async. This works well, unless I try to pass an argument to my callback in `setTimeout`:

## This is async:

```
var callback_function = function (funcArg) {
    console.log("From Main Function");
    setTimeout(funcArg, 10); // WATCH THIS LINE
    console.log("From Main Function 2");
};

callback_function(function (arg) {
    console.log("From Callback");
    console.log(arg);
});

console.log("This should run before callback");
```

**Output:**
From Main Function
From Main Function 2
This should run before callback
From Callback
undefined

## This is not async:

```
var callback_function = function (funcArg) {
    console.log("From Main Function");
    setTimeout(funcArg("Test"), 10); // WATCH THIS LINE
    console.log("From Main Function 2");
};

callback_function(function (arg) {
    console.log("From Callback");
    console.log(arg);
});

console.log("This should run before callback");
```

**Output:**
From Main Function
From Callback
Test
From Main Function 2
This should run before callback

Any idea why this is happening? And how can I run the function asynchronously despite passing in an argument?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing a function to `setTimeout` but calling your function and passing the result.

Change

```
setTimeout(funcArg("Test"), 10);
```

to

```
setTimeout(function(){ funcArg("Test")}, 10);
```