# setTimeout with a local variable?

Tags: javascript

```
function doAnimation(element, stuff){           
    setTimeout(animate(element, stuff), 1000);              
    }

function animate(element, stuff) {
}
```

Is there a simple solution to my problem? I have looked all over the place but cannot find what I am looking for.

Comment: Please include more detail about what you're trying to do, what isn't working, etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Comment: What is the problem??????????????????????????????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
function doAnimation(element, stuff){           
  setTimeout(function () { animate(element, stuff) }, 1000);              
}

function animate(element, stuff) {
}
```