# Running setTimeout() for a Specific DOM Element

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit, settimeout

I have the following code, the problem with that is, if you right click and select 'Copy' on other elements on the page before *setTimeout()* ends, the previously clicked element won't change its style, because of the global variable being assigned with new element value.

How to modify this so *setTimeout()* completes its task for the called element?

```
var whichNode;
var contextMenu = new gui.Menu()

contextMenu.append(new gui.MenuItem({
    label: 'Copy',
    click: function() {
        whichNode.style.color = '#40c4ff'
        setTimeout(function(){ whichNode.style.color = 'inherit' }, 1000)
    }
}))

document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    whichNode = e.srcElement;
    contextMenu.popup(e.x, e.y)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply mantain a copy of the reference to whichNode.
Maybe doing:

```
contextMenu.append(new gui.MenuItem({
label: 'Copy',
click: function() {
  var nodeCopy = whichNode;
  nodeCopy.style.color = '#40c4ff'
  setTimeout(function(){ nodeCopy.style.color = 'inherit' }, 1000)
}
}))
```

is enough.

Comment: Ahh.. I did the same before except I put the new variable in setTimeout()... This works thanks!

Comment: Be careful not all browser support additional paremteres in setTimeout. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback  secondo answer, secondo comment. Also calling the anonymous function is not a standard.