# setTimeout refuses to send the parameters to callback

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments, settimeout

I was allways certain that all the additional parameters you pass to `setTimeout` will be forwarded to the callback:

```
function say(what) {
  alert(what);
}
setTimeout(say, 500, "Hello world.");
```

MDN confirms this belief of mine:

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, [delay, param1, param2, ...]);
```

But not so much the actual code:

```
function reload(cb) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", location.href);
  //Call the callback on request completion
  req.onload = function() {
    console.log("Reloaded, calling callback.");
    if(cb!=null)
      cb();
    else
      console.log("  Callback is null.");
  }
  //Debug info
  console.log("Sending request. Callback: "+cb);
  console.log("   Arguments: "+arguments.length);
  req.send(); 
}
function waitReload() {
  console.log("Reload in 20 ms.");
  //Sending 3 arguments in 20ms
  setTimeout(reload, 20, waitReload, "BLE", "Number 666");
}
waitReload();
```

<sup>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/kotz77m6/)</sup>

This prints out:

```
Reload in 20 ms.
Sending request. Callback: undefined
  Arguments: 0
Reloaded, calling callback.
  Callback is null.
```

No arguments are sent to the callback function. Why? The first code doesn't work either, it alerts `undefined`.

Comment: Note that as a workaround, you can use `setTimeout(function() { say("Hello World"); }, 500);`

Comment: This code's working on Mozilla 37.0.2.. I  see Arguments: 3.

Comment: The code works for me as well, in chrome 42.0.2311.135 m.

Comment: It works in Google Chrome 42.0.2311.135 as well

Comment: works in chrome...  but not in IE.. see this similar but IMHO not duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback

Comment: You already checked MDN, but you didn't read it completely: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/setTimeout . It says something in the lines of `Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and below`

Comment: why don't you use `setTimeout(say.bind(null, 'Hello'), 500);`?

Comment: @devnull69 I am using firefox 33.1.1. Not working.

Comment: Hmm, I am using Firefox 37.0.2 and your fiddle is working perfectly fine, it gives out the callback function and parameters in console 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter syntax is not supported in IE9 and below.

For convinience and cross browser compatibility you should use following syntax, when you need to pass parameters:

```
setTimeout(function(){myFunction(param1,param2);} ,5000);
```

Comment: It's not working for me in firefox 33.1.1. I am pretty sure this is an old syntax that was probably supported in all firefoxes including version 3 years ago.

Comment: This is definitely working in Firefox versions down to version 3 as long as you obey the closure rules

Comment: @devnull69 Well what is it then? For now, I used the anonymous method solution, but I don't like spamming anonymous methods when it's not necessary. Could be a release-specific bug?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing, but this code definitely works in all browsers for years now. There must be some other problem with your code. I mean: The code you posted above is surely not working as you expect. For example: What is waitReload, when you pass it? undefined. If you want to pass a function, write it in a variable first.

Comment: @mondjunge You're wrong about that one. Functions can be passed by their names and they can also be refferenced to as variables. Even `myFunction.prop = true` is perfectly valid and often used to simulate static variables.