# Put a function in suspent

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

In node.js , I need to call a function as soon as a variable is changing.

so what I am doing right now is:

```
var globalvar = 0;



function abc(localvar) {
  if (globalvar == 1) {
    //some stuff
  } else {
    setTimeout(abc(localvar), 1000);
  }
}
abc(localvar);
```

But my server crashes with "Maximum call stack size exceeded."

If I do `setTimeout(function(){abc(localvar);}, 1000);` instead, will it work? (I can't test it right now)

How can I do?

Comment: You might want to consider using an observable publish/subscribe model if you're doing this a lot, rather than effectively polling for changes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
setTimeout(abc(),1000);
```

which is calling the `abc` function and attempting to set a timeout for its return value, which is understandable in some contexts, you'll have to do

```
setTimeout(abc, 1000);
```

Comment: But I have parameters to give to that function?