# How to implement SetTimeOut function in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, settimeout

I want to show a banner for 5 second and then hide it using setTimeout() in Sencha Touch

Comment: What code have you tried already? What problems are you having with that code?

Comment: Luckily I got the solution.

Comment: If you came up with this answer, please write it up as an answer in the answers section (not as part of the question) and mark it correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ext.Function.defer(function () {
    alert('Anonymous');
}, 5000);
```