# How to call javascript function with arguments with setTimeout

Tags: javascript

The following function shows the alert every 5 seconds:

```
function foo() {
    bar="foo";
    alert (bar);

    setTimeout(foo, 5000);
}

foo();
```

However, when I add arguments to the function and call from `setTimeout`, it no longer waits 5 seconds, it just alerts endlessly without any delay:

```
function foo(bar) {
    bar="foo";
    alert (bar);

    setTimeout(foo(bar), 5000);
}

foo();
```

Why is this and how can I loop through the function with a delay while passing arguments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Comment: `foo(bar)` isn't a function. You've invoked a function and by definition, that invoked function returns something whether the return statement is there or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not working because you are invoking the function when using `setTimeout(foo(bar), 5000)`.

You could use the [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pass the `bar` variable:

```
setTimeout(foo.bind(this, bar), 5000);
```

The first parameter is the value of `this` to be passed to the function. It can be `null` if you don't need it. The following parameters are the arguments that are passed. In this case, `bar` is the first argument.

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript thinks you want to call `foo(bar)` immediately then pass its result into `setTimeout()`, which isn't what you mean. Instead, you should create an anonymous function with your call inside it, like this:

```
function foo(bar) {
    bar = "foo";
    alert(bar);

    setTimeout(function() {
        foo(bar)
    }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the parameters arguments (after the 2nd argument):

```
setTimeout(foo, 5000, bar);
```

Basically, any arguments after the 2nd argument are passed down to the function supplied in the first argument.