# Adding a delay in a javascript loop with variables passed to the function

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, settimeout

I'm trying to build a loop function with a delay.  I've found this solution here:

[How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

...but because I want to use the function several times, I want to pass variables to the function.  This is proving difficult.  For example, say I've got a function called "animate_block" that I want to call with variable "blah". This function itself calls another function with this variable, then moves the variable forward by 1 until it reaches some limit, with a recursive setTimeout so it doesn't all happen at once.  Should it look something like:

```
animate_block(blah)

function animate_block(ab_blah){
    move_block(ab_blah);
    ab_blah = ab_blah +1
    if(ab_blah <= 10){
        setTimeout(animate_block(){ab_blah},30); 
}
```

? And if it shouldn't which bit(s) have I got wrong?

Ta!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` takes a function as first argument. You can create a function on the fly, which has access to the `ab_blah` because functions have access to the parent scope.

```
animate_block(blah);

function animate_block(ab_blah) {
    move_block(ab_blah);
    ab_blah = ab_blah +1
    if (ab_blah <= 10) {
        setTimeout(function() { animate_block(ab_blah); }, 30); 
    }
}
```

Read [this article on closures in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to get a good understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Here the limit is fixed. We use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of the 30ms timeout, as `animate_block` sounds like something `visual`.

```
function moveBlock(position) {
    'use strict';
    console.log('moving to block', position);
    return;
}

function animateBlock(position) {
    'use strict';
    //... in case the call was made with `position` higher then 10 it should not be executed
    if(position <= 10) {
        moveBlock(position);
        //we increase position, but `position++` returns `position` prior to the increment
        if (position++ < 10) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(animateBlock.bind(animateBlock, position));
        }
    }
}

animateBlock(1);
```

Android < 4.4, IE8 and Opera Mini [require](http://caniuse.com/#search=requestAnimationFrame) a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671).

Comment: Thanks - it is visual, but it's changing the co-ordinates of something(s) I'm moving around an html5 canvas.

Comment: @user219142 With canvas `requestAnimationFrame` is recommended,

```if you’re running the animation loop in a tab that’s not visible, the browser won’t keep it running```

[Paul Irish - requestAnimationFrame for Smart Animating](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)