# Calling `Function` vs `Function()` within the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was writing a long polling script and ran into a `too much recursion` error which hung the browser. My goal is to call the same function every 1000ms using `setTimeout()`. Yes, I could use `setInterval()` but it is going to be a long polling script and will be waiting for a server response.

I fixed this by removing the `()` from the function I was calling within the same function.

My script looks like:

```
function messagePolling(){
    console.log("polled")
    setTimeout(messagePolling(),1000) // <--- removing `()` from the function works as intended 
} 

messagePolling();
```

What is the logic behind this? `messagePolling` is a function after all isn't it.

Comment: `messagePolling` is a reference to a function. `messagePolling()` **invokes** the function. You should know that since you have `messagePolling();` in the last line of your code snippet ;) And I'm sure you have passed the return value of a function to other functions before, i.e. `foo(bar())`. This is will call `bar` and pass the return value to `foo`. That's how function invocation works in JavaScript.

Comment: See e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback) or [many other duplicates](https://www.google.de/webhp#q=javascript+settimeout+pass+function+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're absolutely right - `messagePolling` is a function. However, `messagePolling()` is *not* a function. You can see that right in your console:

```
// assume messagePolling is a function that doesn't return anything
messagePolling() // -> undefined
```

So, when you do this:

```
setTimeout(messagePolling(), 1000)
```

You're really doing this:

```
setTimeout(undefined, 1000)
```

But when you do this:

```
setTimeout(messagePolling, 1000)
```

You're *actually passing the function* to `setTimeout`. Then `setTimeout` will know to run the function you passed - `messagePolling` - later on. It won't work if it decides to call `undefined` (the result of `messagePolling()`) later, right?

Answer (score 1):

Written as 
`setTimeout(messagePolling(),1000)` the function is executed **immediately** and a `setTimeout` is set to call `undefined` (the value returned by your function) after one second. (this should actually throw an error if ran inside Node.js, as `undefined` is not a valid function)

Written as `setTimeout(messagePolling,1000)` the `setTimeout` is set to call your function after one second.

Answer (score 0):

When you type `messagePolling` you are passing the function to `setTimeout` as a parameter. This is the standard way to use setTimeout.

When you type `messagePolling()` you are executing the function and passing the return value to `setTimeout`

That being said, this code looks odd to me. This function just runs itself. It's going to keep running itself indefinitely if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere a function name contains "()" it is executed immediately except when it is wrapped in quotes i.e is a string.

Comment: In which case, it is not a _function_ but a _string_. That string will only be then used to execute the function if it gets passed through `eval` which is exactly what `setTimeout` does if you do pass it a string.

Comment: E.g var func = "myFunction()".
setTimout("myFunction()",1000) will still be executed. but not instantly. In short I meant function name as a string or variable can not run on its own when just placed in your code without using other functions.

Comment: _It isn't a function_. That's the point your `func` variable contains a string. It just _happens_ to be code that you can execute, however, you make it sound like it's inherently a delayed execution. It isn't. If you have `setTimeout("a = b + c; console.log(a)")` that will also work, but _only_ because it gets passed through `eval`. If you pass the same string through something that does not do `eval` it will never work.

Comment: Yes it is not a function but a string containing function name and "()" which can be executed as a function so eval("myFunction()")==myFunction()

Comment: I guess what is strange about this answer is that you can say this about any other kind of expression: *"Anywhere you have `1 + 1`, the numbers will be added and you get `2`, except when it is wrapped in quotes, i.e. is a string."*. So, how is having code inside a string relevant here at all? Doesn't really provide any value IMO.

Comment: Example is  var a = myFunction() will be executed while var a = "myFunction()"  will not be executed. It doesn't matter where myFunction() is typed.