# setTimeout with variables passed in fuction

Tags: javascript

I need a delay before executing certain function in java script. I could use setTimeout but the problem is I have two variables passed to function. I need to syntax for setTimeout in this case.Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you read [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) even once?

Comment: Please post your tried example code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function something(val1, val2){
 return val1+val2;
}
setInterval(function(){
 something(23,32);
}, 50);
```

Comment: This one worked!!

Answer (score 5):

In any modern JavaScript environment, you can include arguments after the interval:

```
setTimeout(foo, 2000, 'a', 'b');
```

That will call `foo('a', 'b')` after 2000ms.

In obsolete JavaScript environments (such as those in some obsolete browsers), you have to use a wrapper function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    foo('a', 'b');
}, 2000);
```

**but**, there's a big difference between those two: In the first case, any expressions are evaluated when you call `setTimeout` and the **result** of that evaluation is what gets sent to `setTimeout` and ultimately to `foo`, whereas with the wrapper function, the evaluation happens after the delay, later, when `foo` is called.

You can get the same evaluation behavior as the first by using `Function#bind`:

```
setTimeout(foo.bind(null, 'a', 'b'), 2000);
```

Here's an example of the difference:

```js
var a = 1;
setTimeout(foo, 100, a);            // foo will show 1
a = 2;
setTimeout(foo.bind(null, a), 100); // foo will show 2
setTimeout(function() {
    foo(a);                         // foo will show 3 even though
                                    // we set it *after* scheduling
                                    // the call
}, 100);
a = 3;

function foo(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: beat me by 4 seconds :(

Comment: @Albzi: Meh, SO's about building a source of knowledge. The real problem (and the reason I'm moving this answer elsewhere) is that the question is a duplicate. *Edit:* Actually no, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557081/157247) has it covered. I'll leave this here as the other answers are too vague and don't discuss important aspects, but I'll CW it.

Comment: I agree with you! As a side note - I did not mean to come across confrontational as I think it does unintentionally as I read it back, I just meant that the effort of this question is so low quality that it should have been improved or voted to close. Sorry if I came across rude!

Comment: @Albzi: No worries. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimout(function () {
  yourfunction(variable1, variable2)
}, delay)
```