# Implementation for a function 'callAfter' that enables any function to be called after some specified duration

Tags: javascript, chaining

Edit: This is not the duplicate of how to pass params in setTimeout. Actually, I want to know how can write a function that would be called as a method on the predefined function just like the setTimeout API.

So, How can I write an implementation for a function 'callAfter' that enables any function to be called after some specified duration with certain parameters, with the following mentioned syntax:

Example: Lets say you have a function called 'sum' like so:

```
function sum(a, b) {
 console.log('Sum is: ', a + b);
}
```

Now you should be able to execute: 
sum.callAfter(5000, 8, 9);

which should invoke the function 'sum' after 5 seconds with parameters 8 and 9.

Comment: Use timeout. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Comment: Sounds like an interview/homework question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @lxe Finally, Got a solution using Function prototyping.

Comment: Overriding prototype of Function is neat, but is considered by some to be an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it using Function prototyping:

```
Function.prototype.callAfter = function(){
    if(arguments.length > 1){
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        var time = args.splice(0,1);
        var func = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            func.apply(null, args);
        }, time);
    }
```

}

Comment: Good answer, but as a side note,  it's frowned upon to adjust the prototype of native JavaScript Objects. It works, but it can also cause issues when it comes to maintaining code and incorporating libraries.

Comment: @zfrisch True that. Can you show me a better solution? Actually, I am looking for the better approach.