# Difference between variable and parameters

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I'm working on my first javascript script. 
It's a digital clock. And clicking on different buttons you can have times of different city. 
This is my script:

```
var hourHand = document.getElementById('hourHand');
var minuteHand = document.getElementById('minuteHand');
var secondHand = document.getElementById('secondHand');

function initClock() {
    var offset= +5.5;
    var d = new Date();
    var utc = d.getTime() - (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000 * offset ));
    var date = nd;
    var hour = date.getHours() % 12; // 0 - 23
    var minute = date.getMinutes();
    var second = date.getSeconds();

    var hourDeg = (hour * 30) + (0.5 * minute); // every hour, 30 deg. 30 / 60
    var minuteDeg = (minute * 6) + (0.1 * second); // every minute, 6 deg. 6 / 60
    var secondDeg = second * 6; // 360 / 60

    hourHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + hourDeg + 'deg)';
    minuteHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + minuteDeg + 'deg)';
    secondHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + secondDeg + 'deg)';

    setTimeout(initClock, 1000);
};

initClock();
```

It works in this way but if I try to set *offset* as parameter and not as variable the hands change their position but they don't move every second like before. Can someone help me? Sorry if it could be a stupid question but I'm starting just now with javascript :)

```
   var hourHand = document.getElementById('hourHand');
var minuteHand = document.getElementById('minuteHand');
var secondHand = document.getElementById('secondHand');

function initClock(offset) {
    var d = new Date();
    var utc = d.getTime() - (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000 * offset ));
    var date = nd;
    var hour = date.getHours() % 12; // 0 - 23
    var minute = date.getMinutes();
    var second = date.getSeconds();

    var hourDeg = (hour * 30) + (0.5 * minute); // every hour, 30 deg. 30 / 60
    var minuteDeg = (minute * 6) + (0.1 * second); // every minute, 6 deg. 6 / 60
    var secondDeg = second * 6; // 360 / 60

    hourHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + hourDeg + 'deg)';
    minuteHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + minuteDeg + 'deg)';
    secondHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + secondDeg + 'deg)';

    setTimeout(initClock, 1000);
};

initClock(+5.5);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback

Comment: so just change `setTimeout(initClock, 1000);` to `setTimeout(function(){initClock(offset)}, 1000);`