# javascript setInterval only work once?

Tags: javascript

i need to show current time in html code, but the javascript code only work once?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     function updateClock(ele){
         var current_time = new Date();
         var current_time_str = current_time.toLocaleTimeString();
         ele.text(current_time_str);
         console.log(current_time_str);
     }

   setInterval(updateClock($('#clock')) , 1000 );
 })
```

It's work different some others languages like C,Object-C or Python, it's so misleading for me.

Comment: Related: [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the calling part in a function, because it is called only once and returns `undefined` as calling value.

```
setInterval(() => updateClock($('#clock')), 1000);
```

Another possibillity is to use the third and following arguments of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

```
setInterval(updateClock, 1000, $('#clock'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `updateClock` inside setInterval callback function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function updateClock(ele) {
    var current_time = new Date();
    var current_time_str = current_time.toLocaleTimeString();
    ele.text(current_time_str);
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    updateClock($('#clock'))
  }, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clock"></div>
```