# setTimeout inside Promise object

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, control-flow

I am beginning journey on JS and NodeJS. While writing a hello-world app encountered different behavior of setTimeout. It would be great if I could know the cause of this difference.

**Scenario 1**: response waits for 5 sec
**Scenario 2**: Request get resolved immediately though timeout is set for 5 second

Code difference in two scenario is; in Scenario-1 setTimeout has anonymous function and in scenario-2 it calls another function in the same module.

**calculator.js**

**Scenario-1:**

```
module.exports.addNumbers = function(numberArray){

    return new Promise(function(fullfil, reject){
        setTimeout(() => {
            if(!(typeof numberArray === 'Array'))
                reject('Not number elements found!');
        },5000);
        //fullfil(10000);
    });

}
```

[image]

**Scenario-2:**

```
module.exports.addNumbers = function(numberArray){
    return new Promise(function(fullfil, reject){
        setTimeout(add(numberArray, fullfil, reject),5000);
        //fullfil(10000);
    });
}

function add(numberArray, fullfil, reject){
    if(!(typeof numberArray === 'Array'))
        reject('Not number elements found!');
}
```

[image]

**Router (Same in both scenario):**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var calculator = require('../services/calculator');

router.get('/',function(req,res,next){

    //res.writeHeader(200,{'content-type':'text/plain'});

    res.send('Hello World - ' + JSON.stringify(res));
    console.log(res);
});

router.get('/testpromise',function(req,res,next){

    calculator.addNumbers('First Try')
        .then(function(result){
            res.send(' Final Result ## '+result);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            res.send(' ERROR MSG ## '+err);
            console.error(' ERROR MSG ##' +err);
        });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `setTimeout` needs to be a function to call.

In your first example you are providing such a function (`() => {}`):

```
  setTimeout(() => {
        if(!(typeof numberArray === 'Array'))
            reject('Not number elements found!');
    },5000);
```

In the second example however you are not passing in a function as the first argument, instead you are calling it straight away (hence it gets evaluated there and then).

```
setTimeout(add(numberArray, fullfil, reject),5000);
```

As far as I can see `add(numberArray, fullfil, reject)` does **not** return a function.

You could do this to wrap it into a function:

```
setTimeout(() => add(numberArray, fullfil, reject),5000);
```

or make `add` return a function:

```
function add(numberArray, fullfil, reject){
    return () => {
        if(!(typeof numberArray === 'Array'))
            reject('Not number elements found!');
    }
}
// or 
function add(numberArray, fullfil, reject){
    return function() {
        if(!(typeof numberArray === 'Array'))
            reject('Not number elements found!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It helped indeed!

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo(varOne, varTwo) {
  console.log(varOne, varTwo);
}

setTimeout(foo, 5000, 1, 2); // you pass the parameters after the time parameter

setTimeout(()=> {foo(1, 2)}, 5000); // you call the function inside an anonymous function
```

You can check this for more details :
[How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.