# Javascript code executes differently for setTimeout when a function is passed as argument

Tags: javascript

I executed the following code:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('first'), 0)
console.log('second');
```

and as expeted got the output (since Javascript acts asynchronously) in the following order:

```
second
first
```

But when I changed the first argument of the `setTimeout()` function like so:

```
       //notice the ()=> part is removed
        setTimeout(console.log('first'), 0)
        console.log('second');
```

I get the output in the following order:

```
first 
second
```

It is as if Javascripts starts behaving synchronously again after I removed the `()=>` part of the first argument.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: `console.log('first')` is not a function; it's the *result* of *calling* `console.log()` (always `undefined`).

Comment: In `foo(bar())` `bar` is always executed first and its return value is passed to `foo`. In your first example you pass a function. In your second example you pass the result of calling `console.log('first')`. This has nothing to do with `setTimeout`. All functions work like that.

Comment: why there is a downvote without any explanation?

Comment: [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1190642/4642212)

Answer (score 1):

In the second case `console.log('first')` is returning `undefined` which is passed to the `setTimeout` when you call `setTimeout(console.log('first'), 0)` like this.

The function reference passed is `undefined` and at the same time the `console.log('first')` is also getting executed synchronously.

Therefore there will be no asynchronous behavior in observed output as the `setTimeout` is not executing anything asynchronously as the supplied function reference is `undefined`.