# make wait function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function showWinner(Winner){
    if (Winner === "user"){
        winner.innerHTML = `You Win!`;
    } else if (Winner === "computer") {
        winner.innerHTML = `You Lose!`
    } else {
        winner.innerHTML = `Drawn`;
    }
    gameTable.style.display = "none";
    mainScreen.style.display = "none";
    showResult.style.display = "flex";
}
```

In the above code, I want the function to stop for 2 seconds before changing the styles of the dom elements, how can that be done using pure javascript.

Comment: you can use window.setTimeout(callback,timeInMilliSeconds);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use setTimeout

```
setTimeout(showWinner(Winner),2000);
```

Note time is in milliseconds

Comment: +1 but the syntax is not quite right, it'd have to be `setTimeout(() => showWinner(Winner), 2000);` resp. `setTimeout(function() { showWinner(Winner) }, 2000);`

Comment: Also see here for explanation how to pass the Winner variable to the function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7503942/3177115