# Cannot set innerHTML inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, typeerror, innerhtml

Trying to set the innerHTML of a HTML class which are four boxes, each to be set 3 seconds one after another. I can set the innerHTML without setTimeout when the innerHTML is set to a loading icon. When innerHTML is put inside setTimeout the following is returned: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined'.

Tried to debug my code sending messages to the console and searching stackoverflow but no luck.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("numberBox");


for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML= '';
    x[i].innerHTML= "<div class='loader'></div>"
}

// function to generate array of 4 random numbers
var randomNums = generateRandomNumbers();


for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        x[i].innerHTML= '';
        x[i].innerHTML = randomNums[i];
    }, 3000 * i);
}
```

Would like to know why my innerHTML cannot be set within setTimeout here and possible solutions to my problem.

Comment: Understand closures and setTimeout as pointed out by adr5240

Comment: the short version of these answers is that `var` is horrible and broken, and you should **always** use `let` instead

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a question of the current scope. The setTimeout function creates its own scope that has no reference to the old variable. You'll likely need to redefine what x is inside the timeout or pass the array explicitly to the timeout.

See here for how-to: [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

I would also recommend reading up on closers as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 3):

When you use `var` inside the for-loop the `setTimeout` is actually triggered for the last value of `i` as in `var` the binding happens only once.

This is because the `setTimeout` is triggered when the entire loop is completed, then your `i` will be `4`. Keep in mind that there is a closure because of the callback function you pass in the `setTimeout` call. That closure will now refer to the final value of `i` which is 4.

So in this case when the complete loop has executed the value of `i` is `4` but there are indexes upto `3` in x. That is why when you try to access `x[4]` you get `undefined` and you see `TypeError` to fix this just use `let` for fresh re-binding with the new value of `i` in every iteration:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        x[i].innerHTML= '';
        x[i].innerHTML = randomNums[i];
    }, 3000 * i);
}
```

Also if you cannot use `let` due to browser incompatibility you can do the trick with a IIFE:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      (function(i){
         setTimeout(function () {
           x[i].innerHTML= '';
           x[i].innerHTML = randomNums[i];
         }, 3000 * i);
       })(i);
 }
```

This works because `var` has function scope, so here in every iteration a new scope would be created along with the function with a new binding to the new value of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Because of missing i parameter - timeout probably used last (4) which was out of array.

But you can set&use function parameters by adding next timeout parameters.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("numberBox");


for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML= '';
    x[i].innerHTML= "<div class='loader'></div>"
}

// function to generate array of 4 random numbers
var randomNums = generateRandomNumbers();


for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    setTimeout(function (i) {
        x[i].innerHTML= '';
        x[i].innerHTML = randomNums[i];
    }, 3000 * i, i);
}

function generateRandomNumbers() {
var retVal = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
retVal.push(Math.random());
}
return retVal;
}
```

```html
<div class="numberBox"></div>
<div class="numberBox"></div>
<div class="numberBox"></div>
<div class="numberBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // function to generate array of 4 random numbers
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("numberBox");
    var randomNums = generateRandomNumbers();
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            x[i].innerHTML= '';
            x[i].innerHTML = randomNums[i];
        }, 3000 * i, x);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to a very basic and popular concept of Javascript called [closure](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-closure-settimeout-for-loop/). It can be solved in at least two ways:

1. Using `let`

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("numberBox");


for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    x[j].innerHTML= '';
    x[j].innerHTML= "<div class='loader'></div>"
}

// function to generate array of 4 random numbers
var randomNums = generateRandomNumbers();


for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        x[i].innerHTML= '';
        x[i].innerHTML = randomNums[i];
    }, 3000 * i);
}
```

2. Using IIFE

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("numberBox");


for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML= '';
    x[i].innerHTML= "<div class='loader'></div>"
}

// function to generate array of 4 random numbers
var randomNums = generateRandomNumbers();


for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    setTimeout((function (j) {
        x[j].innerHTML= '';
        x[j].innerHTML = randomNums[j];
    })(i), 3000 * i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `x` in a inner method, that is x is not defined in the scope of  `setTimeout`  that is why you receive that execption

I would suggest you use a `setInterval` function as the solution
Your code:

```
var randomNums = generateRandomNumbers(); 

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 

      setTimeout(function () { 
         x[i].innerHTML= ''; 
         x[i].innerHTML = randomNums[i]; 
     }, 3000 * i); 
}
```

A work around

```
var randomNums = generateRandomNumbers();
let i = 0;
let interval = setInterval(function() {
            if( i != 2){
                    x[i].innerHTML= ''; 
                x[i].innerHTML = randomNums[i];
                    i += 1;
            } else {
                    clearInterval(interval) ;
            }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be caused by several factors.

- Defining the `generateRandomNumbers()` function outside the `setTimeout()` scope.
- Using the `var` definition inside your `for` loop.

```
function generateRandomNumbers() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999) + 10000;
}

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("numberBox");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML= '';
    x[i].innerHTML= "<div class='loader'></div>"
}

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      x[i].innerHTML= '';
      x[i].innerHTML = generateRandomNumbers();
    }, 3000 * i);
}
```

This is a different implementation, but here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g7mondrh/)