# Why my delay does not work for addEventListener - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, post, input, frontend

I have user name text input.
I need to send post-request to server to check if user exist.

I have eventListener which triggers on 'keyup'. However i do not want to send request on every key press. I want to send it only when user stopped typing. For example if there no key presses in 700ms

```
window.onload = function() {

  function check_username(){
    response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    user_exist = response['response']['data']['user_exist'];
    console.log('checking username')
    if (user_exist){
      username_input.style.color = 'var(--main-green)';
    }else{
      username_input.style.color = 'var(--error-red)';
    }
  }
// eventlistener
  var typingTimer;
  username_input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if (username_input.value) {
      console.log('trying to send data to server');
      data = {'request':1,'data':{'username':username_input.value}};
      typingTimer = setTimeout(send_post(data,check_username,'checker'), 700);
    }
  });

}
```

Currently delay does not work - js send requests on every key press.

Comment: you are not passing a function to `setTimeout`, you are *calling* it on the spot.

Comment: yes, i see now (i am more about python). I should write just setTimeout(send_post, 700). However how can i pass arguments, which i need to pass?

Comment: found it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback

Comment: It's all in the duplicate Q&A. For example: `setTimeout(() => send_post(data,check_username,'checker'), 700)`