# this.showBox cannot be found in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

When I `console.log(this.showBox)` within the `setTimeout()`, the `console.log()` returns `undefined`, which is different from the `false` that I was expecting. May I know if the `setTimeout()` makes the `this.keyword` unaccessible? Thanks!

```
<script>
import Block from "./components/Block.vue"
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Block,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isPlaying: false,
      delay: null,
      timer: null,
      reactionTime: 0,
      showBox:false,

    }
  },
  methods: {
    startGame() {
      this.isPlaying = true;
      //this.delay = 2000 + Math.floor(Math.random(1,4000) * 4000)
      this.delay = 1000
      console.log(this.delay)
      console.log(this.showBox)

      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(this.showBox)
      }, this.delay);
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: you need to know how `this` works in javascript - there's much information just on stack overflow about it - hint, instead of `function() {` do `() => {` in the setTimeout

Comment: another way to do it is just to pass the data variable into  setTimeout function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback

Comment: @JaromandaX Hello, thank you very much for this explanation! It works with () => now but I will definitely go check out the resources on the differences between the stuff you mentioned! Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When using this in `setTimeout`, it creates its own context and hence it's become undefined, you can use arrow function to share the same context.

```
setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this.showBox)
      }, this.delay);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, this answer does workout! You are correct that it creates it's own context and therefore I could utilize this keyword. I will go and learn the differences between the 2 soon. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Although there's a correct answer, I still wanna write down an answer as a note that **setTimeout & setInterval** will creates its own context both so that variable **this** can't not be realized.

Comment: Hello, yeah I think so as well. However, when using the ( )=> instead of function( ) { }, I managed to use the this and access the showBox. I think it might have something to do with how this we declare our functions as well. Anyways thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Arrow function works but there is another way you can achieve this. Read about **call, bind and apply** methods.

Your problem can be solved in following way using bind method.
Note: What bind does is it creates a new function and sets **this** to passed value. Refer: [MDN bind() method docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for more info.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   console.log(this.showBox)
}.bind(this), this.delay);
```