# guys how can i add a delay of 30 seconds my function ? I'm new to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, bots, delay

here is the code .
i wrote a comment inside the fuction , thats where i want a 30 seconds delay if possible i don't know if there is a simple prebuilt function in JavaScript that allows a delay of time but here is the code and thnx for your help in advance

```js
function Bot(tb,b,bt,bc){
        do{
            // i want the 30 seconds delay here if possible 
            l=((document.getElementsByClassName("roulette-past-queue--previous-rolls-container horizontal-scroll")[0].innerText).length);
            f = document.getElementsByClassName("roulette-past-queue--previous-rolls-container horizontal-scroll")[0].innerText;
            number = f[l-1];
            number = parseInt(number.replace(" ",""));
            if (number >= 1 && number <= 7){
                LastResult = "red";
            }
            if (number >= 8 && number <= 14){
                LastResult = "black";
            }
            if (number == 0){
                LastResult = "green";
            }
            if(LastResult == bc){
                if (bc == "red"){
                    document.getElementById('bet-input-r').value = bt ;
                    document.getElementById('roulette-btn-red').click();
                }else{
                    document.getElementById('bet-input-r').value = bt ;
                    document.getElementById('roulette-btn-black').click();
                }
                
            }
            if(LastResult != bc){
                if (bc == "red"){
                    document.getElementById('bet-btn-double-r').click();
                    document.getElementById('roulette-btn-black').click();
                    bc = "black"
                    bt= bt*2

                }else{
                    document.getElementById('bet-btn-double-r').click();
                    document.getElementById('roulette-btn-red').click();
                    bc = "red"
                    bt= bt*2
                }
            }

        }while(b<tb && b>bt)

}

balance= document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML;
balance = parseInt(balance.replace(",",""));
bet=10
TargetBalance=9999999999999999
document.getElementById('bet-input-r').value = bet ;
betcolor="black"; 
if (betcolor == "red" ){
    document.getElementById('roulette-btn-red').click();
}else{
    document.getElementById('roulette-btn-black').click();
}



Bot(TargetBalance,balance,bet,betcolor);
```

Comment: You can probably achieve that delay with `setTimeout(func(),time)` function.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` functions?

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout:
`setTimeout(yourFunc, 30000);`

Here yourFunc is your function.

setTimeout runs **atleast** after x number of milliseconds.

If you want to pass params check this : [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Comment: do i have to rewrite my function ?

Answer (score 0):

setinvertal waits for the specified time and then starts working continuously. It is also stopped with Clearinvertal() I hope it helped.

```js
 var seti = setInterval(() => {
            second();
        }, 1000);


        function second(params) {
            clearInterval(seti);
            console.log("delay")
        }
```

settimeout runs once when the page is loaded.

```js
  setTimeout(() => {
        second()
    }, 1000);


        function second() {
            console.log("delay")
        }
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply i didnt understand how it works . can you apply it on my code for example ?

Comment: I guess you didn't give all of your code. However, if you want to delay the function you call at the bottom, you can use it as follows. You should write the function you want to delay where I wrote the code.  setTimeout(() => {
       Bot(TargetBalance,balance,bet,betcolor)
    }, 30000);

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` would help take care of this. It would fire your function every 30 seconds until the condition is met, at which point the interval would be cleared.

The updates to your code below center mainly around these 2 lines

```
const interval = setInterval(() => Bot(TargetBalance, balance, bet, betcolor), (30 * 1000) );
```

and

```
if (!(b < tb && b > bt)) clearInterval(interval)
```

```js
function Bot(tb, b, bt, bc) {
    l = ((document.getElementsByClassName("roulette-past-queue--previous-rolls-container horizontal-scroll")[0].innerText).length);
    f = document.getElementsByClassName("roulette-past-queue--previous-rolls-container horizontal-scroll")[0].innerText;
    number = f[l - 1];
    number = parseInt(number.replace(" ", ""));
    if (number >= 1 && number <= 7) {
      LastResult = "red";
    }
    if (number >= 8 && number <= 14) {
      LastResult = "black";
    }
    if (number == 0) {
      LastResult = "green";
    }
    if (LastResult == bc) {
      if (bc == "red") {
        document.getElementById('bet-input-r').value = bt;
        document.getElementById('roulette-btn-red').click();
      } else {
        document.getElementById('bet-input-r').value = bt;
        document.getElementById('roulette-btn-black').click();
      }

    }
    if (LastResult != bc) {
      if (bc == "red") {
        document.getElementById('bet-btn-double-r').click();
        document.getElementById('roulette-btn-black').click();
        bc = "black"
        bt = bt * 2

      } else {
        document.getElementById('bet-btn-double-r').click();
        document.getElementById('roulette-btn-red').click();
        bc = "red"
        bt = bt * 2
      }
    }
if (!(b < tb && b > bt)) clearInterval(interval)
}

balance = document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML;
balance = parseInt(balance.replace(",", ""));
bet = 10
TargetBalance = 9999999999999999
document.getElementById('bet-input-r').value = bet;
betcolor = "black";
if (betcolor == "red") {
  document.getElementById('roulette-btn-red').click();
} else {
  document.getElementById('roulette-btn-black').click();
}

const interval = setInterval(() => Bot(TargetBalance, balance, bet, betcolor), (30 * 1000) );
```

Comment: ooh thnx . but the the 30s delays happens after while thats why when i try to run this script on a website it crashes i need the 30s delay to happen before while