# Is use of setTimeout(..., 1000) in Promise example possible with 'callAsyncJavaScript'?

Tags: javascript, webview, wkwebview

The WebKit-based [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/) documentation provides a [callAsyncJavaScript() method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3656441-callasyncjavascript) with the following example:

```js
var p = new Promise(function (f) {
   window.setTimeout("f(42)", 1000);
});
await p;
return p;
```

Various attempts to run this example code pattern return the same "Completion handler for function call is no longer reachable" error:

```
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 
"A JavaScript exception occurred" 
UserInfo={
  WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=0, 
  WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage="Completion handler for function call is no longer reachable", 
  WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, 
  NSLocalizedDescription="A JavaScript exception occurred"
}
```

I've tried several tweaks of the example code with `callAsyncJavaScript`. The `callAsyncJavaScript` call always returns with the same "... no longer reachable" error.

Here one variant which runs without error in the browser JS console, that does not work with `callAsyncJavaScript`:

[image]

Why the error? Can the example somehow successfully run with `WKWebView` `callAsyncJavaScript`? If yes, then how?

---

**Additional detail**

*The issue may be that the `Promise` does not properly resolve in the documentation example.*

The code below has added `console.log()` tracing information.

```js
let tracer = "a"
console.log("tracer:", tracer);

f = function (nProperty) {
  let nResult = nProperty * 2
  console.log("nResult:", nResult);
  tracer = tracer + "d"
  console.log("tracer:", tracer);
  return nResult;
};

var p = new Promise(function (f) {
  tracer = tracer + "b"
  console.log("tracer:", tracer);
  window.setTimeout("f(42)", 500);
});

console.log("BEFORE await:", p);
tracer = tracer + "c"
console.log("tracer:", tracer);
await p;

console.log("AFTER await:", p);
tracer = tracer + "e"
console.log("tracer:", tracer);
```

When above is run in the a Firefox JS console, the execution stops at the await statement.  Here's the Firefox JS console output:

```js
tracer: a
tracer: ab
BEFORE await: Promise { <state>: "pending" }
tracer: abc
nResult: 84
tracer: abcd
```

The statement `console.log("AFTER await:", p);` is *never executed.*

---

**And, one more detail...**

From a Swift programmer point of view, one would expect that a successful JavaScript example which is called from the Swift [callAsyncJavaScript(…)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3656441-callasyncjavascript) would *expressly return a useful result* from the JavaScript back to the Swift `Result<Any, Error>)`.

Note that `callAsyncJavaScript(…)` executes a provided `String` of JavaScript as an asynchronous JavaScript function.

```js
// do some JavaScript actions, await a result, and then..
return somthingUseful;
```

Comment: Probably (?) not related but `window.setTimeout("f(42)", 1000);` is very bad practice. Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, you don't need that code `eval`-ed. You just need `window.setTimeout(f, 1000, 42);` or `window.setTimeout(() => f(42), 1000);` See: [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1190642)

Comment: Also not very related but `await p; return p;` doesn't make much sense. `p` is still a promise, so you just await its completion and then return the same promise.

Comment: @VLAZ Agreed, the example could be improved in several ways. The "not working" part appears to be that the `Promise` was not properly _resolved_, as updated in the question.   I did manage to create a working example which is posted as an answer ... although it doesn't look much like the original example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't actually realise that `window.setTimeout("f(42)", 1000);` and the `await p; return p;` came directly from the documentation. For the record, the documentation is completely wrong *and* misleading here. I'll write an answer to explain why their example with the Promise doesn't work in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has a really big problem because the code it shows straight up does not work nor *can* it work.

```
var p = new Promise(function (f) {
   window.setTimeout("f(42)", 1000);
});
```

First of all, this is *very bad practice*. Do not pass strings to `setTimeout` as they will be evaluated as code and that is dangerous and very error prone. Pass a function instead.

The current issue comes that when you pass a string it will not be evaluated in the current scope but the global scope:

```js
const foo = "global";

function test() {
  const foo = "local";
  window.setTimeout("console.log(foo)", 1000);
}

test();
```

Which means that `window.setTimeout("f(42)", 1000);` will not call the function parameter `f` (the resolve function) but attempt to use a global variable called `f` and most likely fail because it does not exist. The promise then is left forever pending.

```js
var p = new Promise(function (f) {
   window.setTimeout("f(42)", 1000);
});

p
  .then(value => console.log(`Completed successfully, value: ${value}`)) 
  .catch(error => console.log(`Promise resulted in error`, error));

//neither of the above triggers because of the error in the console
```

The correct ways to create a promise that will resolve later with `setTimeout` are:

```js
var p1 = new Promise(function (f) {
   window.setTimeout(() => f(42), 1000);
});

var p2 = new Promise(function (f) {
   window.setTimeout(f, 1000, 42);
});

var p3 = new Promise(function (f) {
   window.setTimeout(f.bind(null, 42), 1000);
});


p1.then(value => console.log(`p1: Completed successfully, value: ${value}`));
p2.then(value => console.log(`p2: Completed successfully, value: ${value}`));
p3.then(value => console.log(`p3: Completed successfully, value: ${value}`));
```

See: [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1190642)

Comment: Note: As a Swift developer (and in the Apple `callAsyncJavaScript` doc examples) there is an _implied expectation_ that a working JavaScript example expressly `return somthingUseful;`. The question was updated to express the tacit expectation.

Comment: This answer is accepted because it clearly explains why `"f(42)"` breaks the documentation example. Separately, I've added complementary detail to my answer that a Swift developer might find of practical use. Thanks for contributing your insight.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the *"Completion handler for function call is no longer reachable"* error in the [callAsyncJavaScript()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3656441-callasyncjavascript) documentation example may possibly be that the `Promise` did not `resolve`.

Here is a working `callAsyncJavaScript` example (Swift 5.4, Xcode 15.5, macOS 11.4) which uses `Promise`, `setTimeout`, `await` and resolves to a returned data object.

```js
function getPromise() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve({
              'word': 'epistemology'
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
}

function getResult() {
    return getPromise()
        .then(function(response) {
            return response;
        });
}

let data = await getResult()
    .then(function(result) {
        return result;
    });

return data;
```

---

**Update**

*Read the [answer that VLAZ provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159014/is-use-of-settimeout-1000-in-promise-example-possible-with-callasyncjavas/68193106#68193106) to understand the real reason why `"f(32)"` broke the example provided in Apple's [callAsyncJavaScript()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3656441-callasyncjavascript) documentation (as written at the time of this question).*

Also, the Apple example does run to completion and return a `42` value in both the FireFox JavaScript console and the Swift `callAsyncJavaScript(…)` method when the example is modified per [the answer provide by VLAZ](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3656441-callasyncjavascript).

[image]

The `return` value from JavaScript to Swift, as seen in the Swift LLDB debugger:

```
(lldb) po result
▿ Result<Any, Error>
  - success : 42
```

---

**Addendum: Some Useful Tips**

The Swift `callAsyncJavaScript()` method *executes the provided JavaScript String as an asynchronous JavaScript function* inside a WebKit instance. As such, a JavaScript debugger and `console.log()` are not available to the Swift `callAsyncJavaScript()` method.

Below is an approach which can help provide debugging visibilty to a planned JavaScript `String`.

The FireFox JavaScript console can used to exercise the string inside an `async` function body:

```js
// --- name browser window/tab ---
document.title = "Example 42";

async function callAsyncJavaScript() {
  // --- begin Swift string literal section ---
  let mocklog = "LOG: ";
  
  var p = new Promise(function (f) {
    mocklog += "A ";  
    window.setTimeout(() => f(42), 1000); 
  });
  
  // p: Promise { <state>: "pending" }
  mocklog += "B ";  
  let pResult = await p;
  
  // p: Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: 42 }
  mocklog += `C ${pResult}`;
  return {"pResult": pResult, "mocklog": mocklog}
  // --- end Swift string literal section ---
}

let result = await callAsyncJavaScript();
console.log("Result: ", result)
// Result: Object { pResult: 42, mocklog: "LOG: A B C 42" }
```

The same JavaScript can be placed in a multi-line Swift `String` literal:

```swift
let javaScript_42 = """
    let mocklog = "LOG: ";
    
    var p = new Promise(function (f) {
      mocklog += "A ";
      window.setTimeout(() => f(42), 1000);
    });
    
    // p: Promise { <state>: "pending" }
    mocklog += "B ";
    let pResult = await p;
    
    // p: Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: 42 }
    mocklog += `C ${pResult}`;
    return {"pResult": pResult, "mocklog": mocklog}
    """
```

Swift debugger result:

```
(lldb) po result
▿ Result<Any, Error>
  ▿ success : 2 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : pResult
      - value : 42
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - key : mocklog
      - value : LOG: A B C 42
```

Footnote: A `mocklog` string was added as a substitute for `console.log()` since `console.log` is not available in the Swift `callAsyncJavaScript()`. A `\n` in a regular JavaString `mocklog` string would be `\\n` in a corresponding Swift multiline `String` literal.