# Difference between two ways of resolving a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout, arrow-functions

I would like to understand the difference between the two code snippets, both resolving promises in different ways but receiving the same result (resolving after a second).

Which one is the right way?

```js
function longTask(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000)
)}

longTask().then(() => console.log("done"));
```

```js
function longTask(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000)
)}

longTask().then(() => console.log("done"));
```

Comment: There's no difference in this case.

Comment: They work the same. The only difference is not at all related to promises. You just pass a function reference to `resolve` in one case in the other an anonymous function that calls `resolve`. Promises are irrelevant for this.

Comment: For this scenario the only difference is an extra anonymous function that can be skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, where you're not resolving with a value, there is no difference. In situations where you need to resolve the promise with a value, you would want to use the first example so you can control what is passed into the `resolve` function.

```js
function longTask(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(someResolvedValue), 1000)
)}

longTask().then(() => console.log("done"));
```

Edit: Or you can use the second example and pass the resolved value as the third argument to setTimeout.  thanks to VLAZ for pointing this out.

```js
function longTask(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000, someResolvedValue)
)}

longTask().then(() => console.log("done"));
```

Comment: "*In situations where you need to resolve the promise with a value, you would want to use the first example*" why? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7503942

Comment: That's fair also.  I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 2):

Both are technically the same.

The first solution runs an anonymous function that calls the `resolve`.

The second solution gets a reference to the `resolve` function that gets called in the end as well.