# input onKeyUp Event with timeout

Tags: javascript, events, settimeout, addeventlistener, onkeyup

I am trying to create a simple debounce for text input. Following is the code:

```
<body>
    <input id="myInput" type="text" />
</body>
<script>
    function save(data) {
        console.log('saved!!', myInput.value);
    }

    //function process(e, callback, delay) { signature is changed like this, when we call onKeyUp
    function process(callback, delay) { //signature is changed to this, when we call 'process' directly
        //console.log('e', e, 'callback', callback, 'delay', delay);
        let timer;
        return function () {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, delay);
        }
    }

    function onKeyUp(e) {
        //console.log('onKeyUp')
        process(e, save, 1000)
    }

    //const inp = document.querySelector("#txtInput");
    const inp = document.getElementById("myInput");
    inp.addEventListener(
        'keyup',
        //process(save, 1000) //works
        onKeyUp //-- > does not work
    );
</script>
```

If I simply call `process` function on keyup event, it works as expected.

However, I also want to pass e.target.value, and hence I want to event object as well. Hence, to achieve that when I tried calling another function called `onKeyUp` , which captures event object and when I pass it to `process(e, save, 1000)` the setTimeout isn't getting called and hence save function isn't getting triggered.

My question is what is the difference when we call `process` funtion directly on event listener and when we call another function and pass event object to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `process(save, 1000)` works because it return a function (the anonymous function returned in `process()`) which passes to `inp.addEventListener` as the second parameter

```
inp.addEventListener(
    'keyup',
    process(save, 1000)
);
// equals to 
const callback = process(save, 1000); //get the anonymous function returned in `process()`
inp.addEventListener(
    'keyup',
    callback
); //callback will be called like callback() when keyup
```

but when change it to `onKeyup`, the anonymous function will not be called, so the `setTimeout` won't work, so does the `save` function

```
inp.addEventListener(
    'keyup',
    onKeyup
); // onKeyup will be called like onKeyup() 
function onKeyUp(e) {
    process(e, save, 1000) // process called
}
function process(e, callback, delay) { 
    let timer;
    return function () { // not called, it returns as a function only
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, delay);
    }
}
```

To fix it. you can do

```
function onKeyUp(e) {
    process(e, save, 1000)(); 
}
let timer; //assign the `timer` as a global variable
function process(e, callback, delay) { 
    return function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, delay);
    }
}
```

More further, you don't need `onKeyup` if you just want to get the `event` parameter.In the first code, the anonymous function was called when keyup, it accepted the event parameter already.

```
function process(callback, delay) { 
    let timer;
    return function (e) { // you can get `e` here
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Taurz, thank you. It's little clearer to me now. However, with the above fix, when i type 3 characters in text input, the console logs the message 3 times after 1 second of delay, instead of loggint once, like how it happens when process method is directly called on keyup.

Comment: In your code, `timer` would be assigned each time you call the process, `clearTimeout` won't work, you should assign `timer` as a global variable.